# How do I make go find my package?

Tags: go

Where should I put my package so that it can be imported by another package?

```
$ tree
.
├── main.go
└── src
    └── test.go

1 directory, 2 files

$ cat src/test.go 
package test

$ cat main.go 
package main

import "test"

$ go build main.go 
main.go:3:8: import "test": cannot find package
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set your GOPATH. Put your package foo source(s) in GOPATH/src/optional-whatever/foo/*.go and use it in code as

```
import "optional-whatever/foo"
```

You *don't* need to explicitly install foo, the go tool is a build tool, it will do that automagically for you whenever necessary.

Comment: To clarify: the package will be a directory (e.g. 'foo'). You will import the folder as the module, not the individual source files.

Comment: This answer makes it clear that we need to restrict ourselves to put all packages in `$GOPATH`. I was confused until now. Here's a context - https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/1441

Answer (score 8):

There are a few things that need to happen.  You must install the "test" package first:

```
$ export GOPATH=$(pwd)   # Assumes a bourne shell (not csh)
$ mkdir src/test
$ mv src/test.go src/test/test.go
$ mkdir pkg                 # go install will put packages here
$ go install test           # build the package and put it in $GOPATH/pkg
$ go build main.go
```

Note that it is not necessary to create pkg, as `go install` will do that for you.
Once you've installed the test package (generally a bad name, BTW) `go build main.go` should now give different errors (eg, "imported and not used")

Comment: Cleanest explanation for a novice to date.

Answer (score -3):

maybe, you can put the test.go file in the same directory with the main.go, and 
in test.go, it uses something like this：

```
import "./test"
```