# "unrecognized import path" with go get

Tags: go, installation

I'm trying to install a `web.go`, but running `go get github.com/hoisie/web` returns

```
package bufio: unrecognized import path "bufio"
package bytes: unrecognized import path "bytes"
package crypto/rand: unrecognized import path "crypto/rand"
package crypto/sha1: unrecognized import path "crypto/sha1"
package crypto/tls: unrecognized import path "crypto/tls"
package encoding/base64: unrecognized import path "encoding/base64"
package encoding/binary: unrecognized import path "encoding/binary"
package encoding/json: unrecognized import path "encoding/json"
package errors: unrecognized import path "errors"
package fmt: unrecognized import path "fmt"
```

and this continues for a while with various packages, before returning nothing else. `go env` gives me:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/usr/local/go/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/me/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/me/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

How can I install `web.go`? Using `go get` (rather than `go install`) is what is in the README on the github page. My Go version is `go version go1.2 linux/amd64`.

Comment: Exported GOROOT but no GOPATH? GOROOT differs from GOBIN? How did you install Go? How did you set up your environment?

Comment: I installed go by following the http://golang.org/doc/install page. I wasn't sure what to put for GOPATH.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The issues are relating to an invalid `GOROOT`.

I think you installed Go in `/usr/local/go`.
So change your `GOROOT` path to the value of `/usr/local/go/bin`.

It seems that you meant to have your workspace (GOPATH) located at `/home/me/go`.

This might fix your problem.
Add this to the bottom of your bash profile, located here => `$HOME/.profile`

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

Make sure to remove the old references of `GOROOT`.

Then try installing web.go again.

If that doesn't work, then have Ubuntu install Go for you.

`sudo apt-get install golang`

Video tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PATwIfO5ag

Comment: You should almost never set GOROOT. Your PATH declaration doesn't hit /usr/local/go/bin. Also, should note that the ubuntu packages are a bit behind the official release, which is 1.2.

Comment: When I followed the go install instructions from the official site (install from the tar file into /usr/local) 

I received the error above until I changed the GOROOT as above.

Comment: Just installed fresh golang 1.3 on fedora 20 and `go get` gives the same error. `GOROOT` is set to `/usr`, go itself installed into /usr, not /usr/local. Set `GOPATH` to `$HOME/go`. Any idea what else to check ?

Comment: Answering to myself: unsetting `GOROOT` seem fixed the problem.

Comment: Installing `golang` from apt, instead of `gccgo-go` seems to have resolved this for me.

Comment: +1 for not setting GOROOT. I unset it, made sure it was unset with `echo $GOROOT` then checked that GO still had it in the env with `go env` which it did and it was at `/usr/local/go` where I have go installed (thus no need to set it in any case)

Comment: Using GoClipse I was struggling to select proper `GOROOT` in fedora 23. Using `go env` as advised by @Michael.M helped (and value was `/usr/lib/golang`). Thanks!

Comment: It's amazing how difficult it is to install Go.

Answer (score 39):

I installed Go with `brew` on OSX 10.11, and found I had to set `GOROOT` to:

`/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.5.1/libexec`

(Of course replace the version in this path with go version you have)

Brew uses symlinks, which were fooling the gotool. So follow the links home.

Comment: Ah, finally, I found something that worked. Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 23):

I had exactly the same issue, after moving from old go version (installed from old PPA) to newer (1.2.1) default packages in ubuntu 14.04.

The first step was to purge existing go:

```
sudo apt-get purge golang*
```

Which outputs following warnings:

```
dpkg: warning: while removing golang-go, directory '/usr/lib/go/src' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing golang-go.tools, directory '/usr/lib/go' not empty so not removed
```

It looks like removing go leaves some files behind, which in turn can confuse newer install. More precisely, installation itself will complete fine, but afterwards any go command, like "go get something" gives those "unrecognized import path" errors.

All I had to do was to remove those dirs first, reinstall golang, and all works like a charm (assuming you also set GOPATH)

```
# careful!
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/go /usr/lib/go/src
sudo apt-get install golang-go golang-go.tools
```

Comment: I also had to remove ``/usr/local/go/``

Comment: Also had to remove /usr/bin/go.

Answer (score 8):

`$ unset GOROOT` worked for me. As most answers suggest your GOROOT is invalid.

Answer (score 7):

Because GFW forbidden you to access golang.org !
And when i use the proxy , it can work well.

you can look at the information using command 

`go get -v -u golang.org/x/oauth2`

Comment: This is exactly the problem I have as I'm in China. After setting $http_proxy, I can install the package without error.

Comment: Not only blocked,  but also the DNS is polluted. First go to `http://ping.eu/nslookup/` to find the correct IP of the domain, set that into hosts file,  then use a proxy to download.`export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:1080 https_proxy=127.0.0.1:1080`  Sometimes you just want to say the F word to the Gov

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on MacOS 10.10. And I found that the problem caused by OhMyZsh shell. Then I switched back to bash everything went ok.

Here is my go env

```
bash-3.2$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/bis/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1
```

Comment: Is that `go env` from the when it didn't work or when it did? It probably wasn't "caused by [other shell]", rather it was likely a failure to correctly set `GOPATH` in that other shell. The csh and zsh family of shells do *not* use the same startup files (i.e. no `~/.profile`). In particular `zsh` uses `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile` (where `$ZDOTDIR` defaults to `$HOME`).

Answer (score 2):

The most common causes are:
1. An incorrectly configured GOROOT
       OR
2. GOPATH is not set

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after having upgraded go1.2 to go1.4.

I renamed src to _src in my GOPATH then did a `go get -v`

It worked then I deleted _src.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when installing a different package, and it could be caused by the GOROOT and GOPATH configuration on your PATH. I tend not to set GOROOT because my OS X installation handled it (I believe) for me.

1. Ensure the following in your .profile (or wherever you store profile configuration: .bash_profile, .zshrc, .bashrc, etc):

   ```
   export GOPATH=$HOME/go
   export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
   ```
2. Also, you likely want to `unset GOROOT`, as well, in case that path is also incorrect.
3. Furthermore, be sure to clean your PATH, similarly to what I've done below, just before the GOPATH assignment, i.e.:

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
   export GOPATH=$HOME/go
   export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
   ```
4. Then, `source <.profile>` to activate
5. retry `go get`