# golang go get unrecognized import path

Tags: go

When I tried to run go get in a golang project root path ChaatzFeaturePhoneServer. It prompts

```
  go get
  package FeaturePhoneServer/routers: unrecognized import path "FeaturePhoneServer/routers"
```

I am rather confused about it. What is the possible cause of it? How can I find out the cause and fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Check your `GOPATH` environment variable:

`go` expect to find `FeaturePhoneServer/routers` in `$GOPATH/src` (see [`go build`](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/))
[Avoid relative import paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541170/6309).

If the error persists, you can also check your `GOROOT` and go installation, [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20458796/6309).