# package X unrecognized import path : import path does not begin with hostname

Tags: docker, go

In my Golang/gin project i have a dockerfile. This docker file looks like this

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/myAppName
ADD . /go/src/myAppName
WORKDIR /go/src/myAppName

ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...
RUN go get github.com/pilu/fresh

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["fresh"]
```

When I run the command `docker build . --tag=myAppName:dev` in the root directory of the project where the Dockerfile is located, it runs fine untill it wants to install the packages with the `go get -d -v ./...` command.

My project has a lot of different packages located in the project itself, so when it tries to import those it tells me the following:

```
package myAppName/app: unrecognised import path "myAppName/app" (import path does not begin with hostname).
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202487/docker-golang-package-import-error-import-path-does-not-begin-with-hostname) question and promptly set the `$GOPATH` in my Dockerfile.

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774786/error-import-path-does-not-begin-with-hostname-when-building-docker-with-local/36598380) question and tried building the project the manual way without fresh and their method of not setting the GOPATH at all but doing it through the `WORKDIR` command.

Finally I tried using the `go-wrapper` commands, but these seem to not be available when i try to use them, resulting in the error `command not found: go-wrapper`

Unfortunately neither of these work, thus my question.

Any help or pointers in the right direction are much appreciated.

Comment: Ask yourself: "What does `go get ./...` do? Then ask why you would want this at all? Then remove it. `go get` is **not** about "installing packages", it is about downloading external packages from e.g. github via `git clone`.

Comment: I did question that, but since i have imports for github packages nested in the project, i need to run through the entire project to check for imports

Comment: Then still `go get ./...` is wrong. If the packages you have lying on disk import external dependencies then you should download (go get) these dependencies only. But doing this during docker build is a bad idea. Vendor them (commit to your project SCR) or use a dependency tool like dep (or vgo if feeling nerdy). But don't try go get: There is absolutely no way go accomplish what you need.

Comment: i will look into how to vendor them as it does seem like a good option here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After experimennts I've came to the solution:

1. All dependencies are vendored with `dep`. It's a quite easy and very useful tool - I recommend start using it.
2. All packages (and my own projects's too) are located by their full name - `$GOPATH/src/github.com/username/project/package/etc`
3. Then you may use simple `Dockerfile` like this:

   ```
   FROM golang:latest AS builder

   RUN go version

   COPY . "/go/src/github.com/user/project"
   WORKDIR "/go/src/github.com/user/project"

   RUN set -x && \
     apt-get update && \
     go get github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep && \
     which dep && \
     date

   #RUN go get -v -t  .   # <- alternative way if you really don't want to use vendoring
   RUN set -x && \
     dep ensure -v  && \
     echo "vendor:" && \
     dep status

   RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build  -o /run-file

   CMD ["/run-file"]

   EXPOSE 8000
   ```

Comment: Does this also work if my repository is private ? Do I need to add something if it is ?

Comment: I am also getting that dep is not a command using the docker file you provided

Comment: @duck, that works for my private repo if authorization is well established. (However I use not Github.com, but conceptually it's the same). Sorry, I've forgotten to add how I add dep (I do it in a separate Dockerfile, but it's also possible in-place). UPDATED

Comment: I got dep to install through a simple `RUN` command. but authorisation is still an issue as dep hangs on fetching a private repo. any idea on how i can establish its authorisation ?

Comment: Where’s your code located? At what githostong? GitHub? Gitlab? Your own server? AFAIK dep uses `git clone` under the hood. So you just need to authorize git access from building machine. By IP, token or some other way

Comment: I managed to fix it by passing my github accountname and password as parameters to the docker file using `ARGS` and then setting them like so `RUN echo "machine github.com\n\tlogin $GITHUB_USER\n\tpassword $GITHUB_PASS" >> ~/.netrc`. Only problem I have now, is that golang tries to import packages that i defined inside the project from the wrong vendor folder. But i have made a separate question for that.