# I am having trouble getting golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports

Tags: go

when I get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
```

...I get the following error:

```
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports"
```

and I tried to compile the goimports from source code, so I download it from

http://github.com/golang/tools.git
and
https://github.com/bradfitz/goimports

and how to compile it ?

Comment: `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports` works fine for me. What version of Go do you have? And what is your Go environment like? (`go version` and `go env` output). What does `go get -v -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports` say? If you're going to get source manually you should use git/hg commands to fetch the repository and make sure it ends up in the correct place under `GOPATH` (e.g. under `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools`). As for how to build, see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html); but you really should fix your `go get` problem.

Comment: You're using Linux, right? Which distro? If you're using Ubuntu or any of the other Debian variants, you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23832292/4257217 If you do, make sure you add `/usr/local/go` and `/usr/bin/go` to the `sudo rm -rf` command.

Comment: If that doesn't help, I'm guessing that your $GOROOT is set incorrectly. What does `echo $GOROOT` say? If it says nothing, check whether `/usr/local/go` exists.

Comment: @Dave C Sorry for the late reply. I can't fix the problem of "go get", because the golang.org/x/tools is blocked by the gov.  I tried to run "go build" under each of the folder  golang/tools/  and then, run "go build" under goimports/ , it worked. I got goimport file. I don't know why.  Maybe goimports depend on some packets which need to be build bofore. I am confused how the golang.org/x/tools is organized. If I want to build all of the tools, how to set GOPATH, and where to run "go build"

Answer (score 14):

This answer will give an option to work around a failed `go get` **due to network blocking**.
Note that if there is a configuration problem with your Go installation (such as an incorrect `GOPATH`), such failures should **not** be worked around but the underlying problem fixed; otherwise you'll just have later errors/failures. However, in this specific case apparently the root cause of the failure is unfixable due to no network access to the resource required. (Although I'd have expected a better, more specific error message from `go get` in that case; perhaps instead of just blocking an HTTP request has been replaced with a page that contains some data that confuses `go get`).

First, what is `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports` trying to do. [The documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) says it "downloads and installs the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies."

It's important to realize two things: one, it does this by fetching the package *sources* (usually by cloning a VCS repository) and then building the package(s)/program(s); and two, if the source directory appears to already exist it does *not fetch or update anything*.
The later can cause issues if something undetected went wrong with a previous `go get` as you'll be stuck with the "corrupt" sources. If this happens you can either use the `-u` flag to attempt an update or you can remove the old/corrupt/incomplete directory from your `GOPATH` and try a fresh `go get`.

The documentation also describes how it interprets ["remote import paths"](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths), basically trying to match it to a know code hosting service (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc) or to a remote version control system repository (git, mercurial, etc) or doing an HTTPS/HTTP request and looking for a `meta name="go-import" …` tag.

You can see some of this by using `go get -v`:

```
# go get -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil
golang.org/x/tools/imports
golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
```

In this case `go get` does an HTTPS request to `golang.org` to discover the location of the source and effectively does¹:

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools
git clone https://go.googlesource.com/tools $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools
go build golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
```

It found that `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports` is part of `golang.org/x/tools` and downloads that whole repository by doing a `git clone` and then building the `goimports` command and it's two dependant packages (which conveniently are within the same repository, otherwise there would be multiple clone/download steps). The results are put under `$GOPATH/bin` (and `$GOPATH/pkg/$GOOS_$GOARCH`).

So if `go get` isn't working or is blocked from accessing `golang.org` the first thing to try would be the above commands.
Failing that you could substitute a mirror (e.g. `git clone https://github.com/golang/tools.git $GOPATH/golang.org/x/tools`), or you could otherwise download the contents of the repository from somewhere and unpack them into the correct location within your `GOPATH`, e.g. perhaps something like:

```
curl https://github.com/golang/tools/archive/master.zip
unzip -d $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools master.zip
```

Once the source for all dependant packages is "somehow" put into `GOPATH/src` you should be able to `go build {path}`.
**The important part here is to make sure the sources are where the `go` tools expects them to be**, that is, under `$GOPATH/src/{go/import/path}`.

If only some domains (such as `golang.org`) are blocked you could do this for only the blocked repositories and then do `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports`; since `go get` won't try to fetch existing directories this should only fetch any missing dependencies before building everything.

<sub>¹ Note, these examples assume the common case of `GOPATH` being a single directory. If instead your `GOPATH` is multiple directories, e.g. `GOPATH=$HOME/go.public:$HOME/go.private`, then you'd need to substitute the *first* path component of your `GOPATH`.</sub>

Comment: Note this is all pre-modules. If using [Go 1.11+ with modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) things work slightly differently and the best work around for issues fetching would probably be setting `GOPROXY` and perhaps using a custom proxy.

Comment: `export GOPROXY=https://gocenter.io` was the answer that worked for me, thanks @dave-c

Answer (score 0):

Try these 3 approaches:

1. On Windows, set the proxies in Internet Explorer.
2. Add `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` to your environment variables.
3. If you are using git, edit the .gitconfig file like this:

> ```
> [http]
>    proxy = "your proxy"
> ```