# Go build: “Cannot find package” (even though GOPATH is set)

Tags: go

My question is quite similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214029/go-build-cannot-find-package-even-though-gopath-is-set),different is I have directory hierarchy as best answer pointed out,but I still get same problem,why?

```
$ echo $GOROOT
/usr/local/go

$ echo $GOPATH
/home/mitchell/go

$ cat /home/mitchell/go/src/main.go
package main
import "comment/create"
func main() { }

$ cat /home/mitchell/go/src/comment/create/***.go(bunch of go files)
package create

$ go build main.go
main.go:3:8: import "comment/create": cannot find package
```

Comment: It works in my computer. I suggest to run `go env` and `go build -x main.go` to get more clues.

Comment: maybe the permissions? put the output of the go build

Comment: `main.go` should be in `src/comment/main.go` - i.e. it needs to be in a package itself (either "comment" or "mypackage123"). Also post the output of `go env`.

Comment: @elithrar, although I agree that `main.go` shouldn't be located on `src/main.go`, it doesn't explain the compile failure.

Comment: Did you export $GOPATH? If you don't export it, go won't pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your directory structure is wrong:

go/src/comment/create

should be something like

go/src/github.com/"your git org"/comment/create

For instance, my github organization is SupportLocal, my repo is "Comment", create is my go package name, my directory would look like this:

go/src/github.com/supportlocal/comment/create

Then your import would look like this:

"github.com/supportlocal/comment/create"

Let me know if that works.