# What's the proper way to "go get" a private repository?

Tags: git, go

I'm searching for the way to get `$ go get` work with private repository, after many google try.

The first try:

```
$ go get -v gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go
Fetching https://gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go?go-get=1
https fetch failed.
Fetching http://gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from http://gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go?go-get=1 (status code 200)
import "gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go": parse http://gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags
package gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go: unrecognized import path "gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go
```

Yep, it did not see the meta tags because I could not know how to provide login information.

The second try:

Follow https://gist.github.com/shurcooL/6927554. Add config to .gitconfig.

```
[url "ssh://git@gitlab.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
$ go get -v gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go --> not work
$ go get -v gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go.git --> work but I got src/gitlab.com/secmask/awserer-go.git
```

Yes it work but with `.git` extension with my project name, I can rename it to original but do it everytime `$ go get` is not so good, is there an otherway?

Answer (score 244):

You have one thing to configure. The example is based on GitHub but this shouldn't change the process:

```
$ git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
$ go get github.com/private/repo
```

For Go modules to work (with Go 1.11 or newer), you'll also need to set the `GOPRIVATE` variable, to avoid using the public servers to fetch the code:

```
export GOPRIVATE=github.com/private/repo
```

Comment: Already did that, actually it's only one config to do, `cat` command is just for verify.

Comment: The only drawback with this is that you cant have different config for each host (e.g if you're using multiple providers) without altering the global git configuration for each time. Then it's much better to specify this on «ssh-level» as described her: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository/40795707#40795707

Comment: `go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/<OrgNameHere>/*`as described here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305567/how-to-set-goprivate-environment-variable

Comment: is quotes around url needed like [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45936697/1518100) posts?

Comment: There can be cache messing things up. Probably from attempting to get some repo without changing the git config as described above. What solved it for me :

rm -rf $GOPATH/pkg/mod/cache/vcs

Comment: @LeiYang They are not *strictly* needed, but it's a good idea to put `"quotes"` or `'quotes'` around something that includes special shell characters (like `*` in this case)

Comment: Is anyone able to get this working with gitlab? I keep getting the error `The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.` when I try. I can run git commands via ssh just fine. This only works for me with the token based solution.

Comment: This appears to be broken in 2021 with go 1.16. Git clone works with public and private repos on github but go get (and go mod tidy) fail on the private repo. Oddly enough, the go commands work correctly with private repos on my own gitea server.

Comment: Works like a charm with 1.19! Perhaps a small explanation to help unaware readers: the question tries to replace "https://gitlab.com" with "ssh://git@gitlab.com/", this could work, but using the ssh:// format does not automatically find the .git file that `go get` needs. However, using simply `git@gitlab.com` to replace works, since it automatically returns the .git file that go get expects.

Answer (score 58):

I had a problem with `go get` using private repository on **gitlab** from our company.
I lost a few minutes trying to find a solution. And I did find this one:

1. You need to get a private token at:
   https://gitlab.mycompany.com/profile/account
2. Configure you git to add extra header with your private token:

   ```
    $ git config --global http.extraheader "PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN"
   ```
3. Configure your git to convert requests from *http* to *ssh*:

   ```
    $ git config --global url."git@gitlab.mycompany.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.mycompany.com/"
   ```
4. Finally you can use your `go get` normally:

   ```
    $ go get gitlab.com/company/private_repo
   ```

Comment: Interesting use of `http.extraheader`. +1

Comment: will `--global` also send your private token to other git server in case you using many repo? any secure risk?

Comment: Anyone any review on that? I think it will send it to public github repo when we do go get on them

Comment: There is another option where you send token only to your gitlab - but I am not sure this is encoded.
`git config --global url."https://${user}:${personal_access_token}@mygitlab.com".insteadOf "https://mygitlab.com"`

Comment: I think @S.R solution is best (even though I had to add a trailing slash to the first url to make it work for my case => `[...] url."https://${user}:${personal_access_token}@mygitlab.com/".insteadOf [...]`

Comment: @secmask SSH protocol doesn't "send your private token" to anybody. [Based on this](https://serverfault.com/a/142865/243251) The SSH "server uses your public key to sign a challenge, and your client uses your private key `id_rsa` to decrypt the challenge, re-encrypt it with the server's public `host key` and send it back." There's a privacy risk if you don't want the public server tracking you by the SSH key you've added to your SSH agent.

Comment: This has to be the correct answer

Answer (score 56):

The proper way is to manually put the repository in the right place. Once the repository is there, you can use `go get -u` to update the package and `go install` to install it. A package named

```
github.com/secmask/awserver-go
```

goes into

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/secmask/awserver-go
```

The commands you type are:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/secmask
git clone git@github.com:secmask/awserver-go.git
```

Comment: @secmask `go get` is designed as a tool for the common case. The Go team explicitly decided against adding configurability so people adhere to standards instead of rolling out their own cruft. It was never made for the case you have (i.e. private repositories).

Comment: This is an interesting perspective, but the big limitation of this approach is the handling of recursive, private dependencies. Handling this in a scalable way would essentially require re-implementing `go get`, if SSH access couldn't be handled as described in other answers.

Answer (score 49):

For people using private GitLabs, here's a snippet that may help: https://gist.github.com/MicahParks/1ba2b19c39d1e5fccc3e892837b10e21

Also pasted below:

## Problem

The `go` command line tool needs to be able to fetch dependencies from your private GitLab, but authenticaiton is required.

This assumes your private GitLab is hosted at `privategitlab.company.com`.

## Environment variables

The following environment variables are recommended:

```bash
export GO111MODULE=on
export GOPRIVATE=privategitlab.company.com # this is comma delimited if using multiple private repos
```

The above lines might fit best in your shell startup, like a `~/.bashrc`.

#### Explanation

`GO111MODULE=on` tells Golang command line tools you are using modules. I have not tested this with projects not using
Golang modules on a private GitLab.

`GOPRIVATE=privategitlab.company.com` tells Golang command line tools to not use public internet resources for the hostnames
listed (like the public module proxy).

## Get a personal access token from your private GitLab

To future proof these instructions, please follow [this guide from the GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token).
I know that the `read_api` scope is required for Golang command line tools to work, and I may suspect `read_repository` as
well, but have not confirmed this.

## Set up the `~/.netrc`

In order for the Golang command line tools to authenticate to GitLab, a `~/.netrc` file is best to use.

To create the file if it does not exist, run the following commands:

```bash
touch ~/.netrc
chmod 600 ~/.netrc
```

Now edit the contents of the file to match the following:

```
machine privategitlab.company.com login USERNAME_HERE password TOKEN_HERE
```

Where `USERNAME_HERE` is replaced with your GitLab username and `TOKEN_HERE` is replaced with the access token aquired in the
previous section.

## Common mistakes

Do **not** set up a global git configuration with something along the lines of this:

```bash
git config --global url."git@privategitlab.company.com:".insteadOf "https://privategitlab.company.com"
```

I beleive at the time of writing this, the SSH git is not fully supported by Golang command line tools and this may cause
conflicts with the `~/.netrc`.

## Bonus: SSH config file

For regular use of the `git` tool, not the Golang command line tools, it's convient to have a `~/.ssh/config` file set up.
In order to do this, run the following commands:

```bash
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Please note the permissions on the files and directory above are essentail for SSH to work in it's default configuration on
most Linux systems.

Then, edit the `~/.ssh/config` file to match the following:

```
Host privategitlab.company.com
  Hostname privategitlab.company.com
  User USERNAME_HERE
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Please note the spacing in the above file matters and will invalidate the file if it is incorrect.

Where `USERNAME_HERE` is your GitLab username and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the path to your SSH *private* key in your file system.
You've already uploaded its *public* key to GitLab. Here are [some instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account).

Comment: There's something that always rubbed me the wrong way about configuring git globally just so that Go dependencies can be downloaded. But doesn't this have that same problem? You're configuring a tool used by your entire system (in this case, if I understand .netrc properly, the way your machine performs every HTTP request) just so that Go dependencies can be downloaded. In fact, this way seems risky, since wouldn't it include that token with every request you send to that host?

Comment: Thank you, For gitlab the following worked for me `echo "machine gitlab.example.com login gitlab-ci-token password ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc
 && chmod 600 ~/.netrc`

Comment: Thanks! Little note for windows: %HOME%\\_netrc file there.

Answer (score 27):

All of the above did not work for me. Cloning the repo was working correctly but I was still getting an `unrecognized import` error.

As it stands for Go v1.13, I found in the doc that we should use the [GOPRIVATE](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_configuration_for_non_public_modules) env variable like so:

```
$ GOPRIVATE=github.com/ORGANISATION_OR_USER_NAME go get -u github.com/ORGANISATION_OR_USER_NAME/REPO_NAME
```

Comment: That was so simple... made my day!

Answer (score 19):

Generate a github oauth token [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new) and export your github token as an environment variable:

```
export GITHUB_TOKEN=123
```

Set git config to use the basic auth url:

```
git config --global url."https://$GITHUB_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Now you can `go get` your private repo.

Comment: best answer for Dockerfile, thank you Miguel Mota

Comment: This works as of today. Other solutions does not provide option to provide token or username/token

Answer (score 15):

If you've already got git using SSH, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672481/2014893) by [Ammar Bandukwala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5125201/ammar-bandukwala) is a simple workaround:

---

`$ go get` uses `git` internally. The following one liners will make `git` and consequently `$ go get` clone your package via SSH.

Github:

```
$ git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

BitBucket:

```
$ git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"
```

Answer (score 13):

I came across `.netrc` and found it relevant to this.

Create a file `~/.netrc` with the following content:

```
machine github.com
    login <github username>
    password <github password or Personal access tokens >
```

Done!

Additionally, for latest GO versions, you might need to add this to the environment variables `GOPRIVATE=github.com/<orgname|username>`
(I've added it to my `.zshrc`)

`netrc` also makes my development environment setup better as my personal github access for HTTPS is been configured now to be used across the machine (just like my SSH configuration).

Generate GitHub personal access tokens: https://github.com/settings/tokens

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031266) for its use with Git on Windows specifically

Ref: [netrc man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc)

---

**If you want to stick with the SSH authentication, then mask the request to use ssh forcefully**

`git config --global url."git@github.com:<orgname|username>".insteadOf "https://github.com/<orgname|username>"`

Replace `<orgname|username>` with your GitHub org name or username.

---

Issue is that, go tries to access the dependencies using https protocol and lot of us use ssh instead to authenticate on git. So we either need to setup a https authentication using `~/.netrc` or force using ssh on all request to a specific git location using `git config`

More methods for setting up git access: https://gist.github.com/technoweenie/1072829#gistcomment-2979908

Comment: This requires you to store your login credentials in a plain text file on your machine. That's not good.

Comment: You are probably right. For me, it looks similar to how AWS credentials are stored in `~/.aws`. And with GitHub's personal access token, I can fine grain the access according to requirement and control rotations.
There's SSH way as well 

Answer (score 10):

2023: `.git` is no longer required on GitHub repos access over ssh.
The same should apply to GitLab.

---

2014: That looks like the [GitLab issue 5769](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5769).

> In GitLab, since the repositories always end in `.git`, I must specify `.git` at the end of the repository name to make it work, for example:
>
> ```
> import "example.org/myuser/mygorepo.git"
> ```
>
> And:
>
> ```
> $ go get example.org/myuser/mygorepo.git
> ```
>
> Looks like GitHub solves this by appending `".git"`.

It is supposed to be resolved in “[Added support for Go's repository retrieval. #5958](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5958)”, provided the [right meta tags are in place](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5958#issuecomment-58987846).
Although there is still an issue for Go itself: “[`cmd/go`: go get cannot discover meta tag in HTML5 documents](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8163)”.

Comment: Actually they (and others) has already supported meta tags, but it just works for public repo (where `go get` can see meta tags without login)

Comment: @secmask which is why you are using ssh: to provide the credentials that way.

Comment: oh, that just option, I can use http,https to but `go get` command will look like `go get gitlab.com/secmask/awserver-go.git.git` (will ask http basic authenticate), which look not good too.

Comment: I suspect this answer is out of date now, as `.git` is no longer required on github repos access over ssh

Comment: @erik258 True, and the same should apply for GitLab, I presume.

Answer (score 9):

After trying multiple solutions my problem still persisted. The final solution after setting up the `~/.netrc` and SSH config file, was to add the following line to my `~/.bash_profile`

`export GOPRIVATE="github.com/[organization]"`

Answer (score 6):

I have created a user specific ssh-config, so my user automatically logs in with the correct credentials and key.

First I needed to generate an key-pair

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my@email.here"
```

and saved it to e.g `~/.ssh/id_my_domain`. Note that this is also the keypair (private and public) I've connected to my Github account, so mine is stored in`~/.ssh/id_github_com`.

I have then created (or altered) a file called `~/.ssh/config` with an entry:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_github_com
```

On another server, the "ssh-url" is `admin@domain.com:username/private-repo.git` and the entry for this server would have been:

```
Host domain.com
    HostName domain.com
    User admin
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_domain_com
```

Just to clarify that you need ensure that the `User`, `Host` and `HostName` is set correctly.

Now I can just browse into the go path and then `go get <package>`, e.g `go get main` where the file `main/main.go` includes the package (from last example above) `domain.com:username/private-repo.git`.

Comment: You can also import a package directly with:
`go get hostname.com/username/repo.git` (.git extension is crucial).

Comment: is there any way to do it without the extension `.git` and why happen it?

Comment: Interesting, the reason cause I don't be able to get the repo, without the `.git` extension  it was that on my local  git configuration, `git config --global url."git@gitlab.myserver.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.myserver.com/"` , but the subdomain `gitlab.myserver.com` doesn't have the ssl certification, so  I use `http` instead of `https` , by now

Answer (score 4):

For me, the solutions offered by others still gave the following error during `go get`

> git@gl.nimi24.com: Permission denied (publickey).
>    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>    and the repository exists.

**What this solution required**

1. As stated by others:

   `git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`
2. Removing the passphrase from my `./ssh/id_rsa` key which was used for authenticating the connection to the repository. This can be done by entering an empty password when prompted as a response to:

   `ssh-keygen -p`

**Why this works**

This is not a pretty workaround as it is always better to have a passphrase on your private key, but it was causing issues somewhere inside OpenSSH.

`go get` uses internally git, which uses openssh to open the connection. OpenSSH takes the certs necessary for authentication from `.ssh/id_rsa`. When executing git commands from the command line an agent can take care of opening the id_rsa file for you so that you do not have to specify the passphrase every time, but when executed in the belly of go get, this did not work somewhy in my case. OpenSSH wants to prompt you then for a password but since it is not possible due to how it was called, it prints to its debug log:

> read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

And just fails. If you remove the passphrase from the key file, OpenSSH will get to your key without that prompt and it works

This **might** be caused by Go fetching modules concurrently and opening multiple SSH connections to Github at the same time (as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@tim_raymond/fetching-private-dependencies-with-go-modules-1d65afe47c62)). This is somewhat supported by the fact that OpenSSH debug log showed the initial connection to the repository succeed, but later tried it again for some reason and this time opted to ask for a passphrase.

However the solution of using SSH connection multiplexing as put forward in the mentioned article did not work for me. For the record, the author suggested adding the collowing conf to the ssh config file for the affected host:

```
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 3600
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
```

But as stated, for me it did not work, maybe I did it wrong

Comment: I think you can get this to work without removing the passphrase on your SSH key by using ssh-agent before running go-get to pre-authenticate your ssh-key.

Comment: In my case using an agent beforehand did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

After setting up `GOPRIVATE` and `git config ...`

People may still meeting problems like this when fetching private source:

```
https fetch: Get "https://private/user/repo?go-get=1": EOF
```

They can't use private repo without `.git` extension.

The reason is the go tool has no idea about the VCS protocol of this repo, `git` or `svn` or any other, unlike `github.com` or `golang.org` them are hardcoded into go's source.

Then the go tool will do a `https` query before fetching your private repo:

```
https://private/user/repo?go-get=1
```

If your private repo has no support for `https` request, please use `replace` to tell it directly :

```
require private/user/repo v1.0.0

...

replace private/user/repo => private.server/user/repo.git v1.0.0
```

https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths

Answer (score 2):

first I tried

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

but it didn't worked for my local.

I tried

`ssh -t git@github.com`

and it shows my ssh is fine.

finally, I fix the problem to tell the go get to consider all as private and use ssh instead of HTTPS.

adding `export GOPRIVATE=*`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you remove your previous gitconfigs, I had the same issue.

Previously I executed `gitconfig` whose token was expired, when you execute the command next time with new token make sure to delete previous one.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the existing answers with GitLab Enterprise Edition 15.11.11-ee and none worked.

With our instance of Gitlab I found `go get` only works if your repository (repo) is **not** in a [**sub**group](https://archives.docs.gitlab.com/15.11/ee/user/group/subgroups/)

Imagine the domain name is `https://gitlab.company-name.com`

If the path of the repo URL is
`/repository` or `group/repository`.

`go get` will work.

However, if you have a subgroup i.e the repo URL path is
`group/subgroup/repository` `go get` will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

For standalone/final repos, an as a quick fix, why don't just to name the module within the go.mod as a package using your company's domain ... ?

```
module go.yourcompany.tld/the_repo
```

`go.yourcompany.tld` don't even have to exist as a valid (sub)domain...

Also, in the same `go.mod` you can use `replacement` block/lines to use private repos previously cloned the same way (within a respective folder cloned also in `$GOPATH/src/go.yourcompany.tld`) (why do we have to depend too much in GitHub?)

Edit

1. Needless to say that a private repo usually shall be a private repo, typically a standard git repo, right? With that, why not just to `git clone` and then `go get` within the cloned folder?

Answer (score -1):

It's Hard Code In Go Get. Not The Git Reason. So Modify Go Source.
**Reason**:
repoRootForImportDynamic Will Request: https://....go-get

```
// RepoRootForImportPath analyzes importPath to determine the
// version control system, and code repository to use.
func RepoRootForImportPath(importPath string, mod ModuleMode, security web.SecurityMode) (*RepoRoot, error) {
    rr, err := repoRootFromVCSPaths(importPath, security, vcsPaths)
    if err == errUnknownSite {
        rr, err = repoRootForImportDynamic(importPath, mod, security)
        if err != nil {
            err = importErrorf(importPath, "unrecognized import path %q: %v", importPath, err)
        }
    }
    if err != nil {
        rr1, err1 := repoRootFromVCSPaths(importPath, security, vcsPathsAfterDynamic)
        if err1 == nil {
            rr = rr1
            err = nil
        }
    }
```

So add gitlab domain to vcsPaths will ok.
Download go source code:

```
vi ./src/cmd/go/internal/vcs/vcs.go
```

Look for code below:

```
var vcsPaths = []*vcsPath{
    // GitHub
    {
        pathPrefix: "github.com",
        regexp:     lazyregexp.New(`^(?P<root>github\.com/[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+)(/[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+)*$`),
        vcs:        "git",
        repo:       "https://{root}",
        check:      noVCSSuffix,
    },
```

add Code As Follow,XXXX Is Your Domain:

```
    // GitLab
    {
        pathPrefix: "gitlab.xxxx.com",
        regexp:     lazyregexp.New(`^(?P<root>gitlab.xxxx\.com/[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+)(/[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+)*$`),
        vcs:        "git",
        repo:       "https://{root}",
        check:      noVCSSuffix,
    },
```

compile and replace go.