# Go get -insecure my.domain.com

Tags: go

I have a a Golang Git project.

I tried to use `go get -insecure my.domia.com/alerts`

but i got the fellowing error.

```
OK: 214 MiB in 23 packages
Fetching https://my.domia.com/alerts?go-get=1
https fetch failed: Get https://my.domia.com/alerts?go-get=1: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
Fetching http://my.domia.com/alerts?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from http://my.domia.com/alerts?go-get=1 (status code 404)
package my.domia.com/alerts: unrecognized import path "my.domia.com/alerts" (parse http://my.domia.com/alerts?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags)
```

Could any one help please? I really appreciate it.

Or, if anyone could help to install manually.

Thanks,

Comment: https://golang.org/s/go14customimport discusses how `go get` works with custom domains. All that I can tell here is that the URL corresponding to this package path 404s.

Comment: See if this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27500861/1144203) helps.