# 'Go Get' Private Repo from Bitbucket

Tags: git, go, bitbucket

So basically, I have an Openshift Project that on Git push, downloads all libraries with 'Go get' and builds the project on-the-fly and so, I have some code I don't want people to see from my own library, and for it to compile properly, the code needs to be taken from github.com or another repo, so I created a private bitbucket.org repo, now, as a public repo it works fine, but when I try to 'Go Get' from my private repo, it gives me 'Forbidden 403'

How can I avoid this occurency?
Thank you for reading and have a nice day!

Comment: you are using *pipelines* from BitBucket right? same problem I added an SSH key pair and added `bitbucket.org` as a know host but I still get `403`. I think there is something missing in https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/DBuDMg since we can't add the PubKey to the remote hosts on Bitbucket.

Comment: Since go@1.13 you need to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470626/how-do-i-use-go-with-bitbucket-private-repositories/61474660#61474660).

Answer (score 83):

`go get` uses `git` internally. The following one liners will make `git` and consequently `go get` clone your package via SSH.

Github:

`git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`

BitBucket:

`git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"`

Comment: Still getting 403 error for bitbucket after adding to global config, what other reasons could there be for this and how to solve?

Comment: i'm able to push to and pull from my repo using ssh, not sure how why go get is not seeing this config change, and i'm also getting same error when i put this config change in my local .git/config

Comment: btw, i'm doing the go get while building the docker image for my go app, not sure if it could be related to that too

Comment: I faced the same issue @user3226932 faced: even after adding global config was getting 403 error. Solved it by doing `git config --system`: `git config --system url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`.

Comment: Still didn't work after the command above, but the error mentioned that it goes to api.bitbucket.org, so I used:
`git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://api.bitbucket.org/"`

Comment: Both tipps in combination helped me, when I tried to use go modules with a public bitbucket repository on windows: `git config --system url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://api.bitbucket.org/"`

Comment: I was using my personal private bit bucket repo. follow helped me
--> `export GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/companyNameORuserName`
--> `git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"`

Answer (score 19):

Adition to setting `git config` described by others, I had to set `GOPRIVATE`.

Step 1. `git config --global url."git@bitbucket.<YOUR-COMPANY>".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/<YOUR-COMPANY>"`

Step 2. `export GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/<YOUR-COMPANY>`

the `GOPRIAVTE` is documented here: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_configuration_for_non_public_modules

Comment: With private modules hosted on GitHub setting `GOPRIVATE` as advised worked but differently from your example I had to modify git configuration with a specific authentication url e.g. `git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_USER}:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"`. If the repository is private how do you authenticate?

Comment: Thank you @MarcoDufal, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

[Ammar Bandukwala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672481/2728986) is correct, but if you find yourself behind a firewall with SSH outgoing port (22) closed, you can use SSH over HTTPS port (443) instead:

```
git config --global url."ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/<account_name>".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/<account_name>"
```

source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html#TroubleshootSSHissues-Ifport22isblocked

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here after trying all of the above (and getting a 404 instead of a 403) this is because BB changed the response code from 403 to 404 when you're fetching a private repo. Golang has a fallback to HTTP when the repo cannot be resolved through SSH. This was fixed in golang version 1.16+.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).