# go get a private repo from codecommit

Tags: go, aws-codecommit, go-get

I'm new to golang, we are trying to create a package in go and use across all the services we wanted to use.

I tried to create a repo in github and tried to do go get; I didn't get any issue.

Now I wanted to create the same package in codecommit of amazon. I add my ssh in iam of aws, and I'm able to clone.

I ran these commands:

```
$ git config --global url."ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:".insteadOf "https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"
$ go get git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-package
```

And I got below error:

```
package git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-package: unrecognized import path "git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-package" (parse https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-package?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

Could someone solve my issue with codecommit?

I'm able to do this in github, but I'm getting issue in codecommit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to "go get" a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository)

Comment: Tried this already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668444/go-get-private-repo-from-bitbucket/38672481#38672481 I'm getting above error

Comment: it looks like go-get is automatically using https:// instead of ssh://

Answer (score 0):

Your second command looks fine,

`go get git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-package`

You just need to add `.git` to the end of it i.e.

`go get git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-package.git`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding '.git' e.g:

```
$ go get git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-package.git
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.