# Get a private repository from AWS codecommit using HTTPS GRC

Tags: go, aws-codecommit, go-modules, go-get

I'm trying to import a module located in AWS codecommit. To clone the repository I'm using HTTPS GRC (Git Remote Codecommit) method, which uses Google Suite credentials to access AWS console.

The command I use to clone the repository is:

```
git clone codecommit::us-west-2://my-module
```

The remote module's `go.mod` file contains this:

```
module git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-module.git
```

I tried to achieve my goal configuring Git like this:

```
git config --global url."codecommit::us-west-2://".insteadOf "https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
```

Setted GOPRIVATE:

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-module.git
```

And then getting the repository:

```
go get -x git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-module.git
```

but I get this output (and the execution gets stuck):

```
cd.
git ls-remote https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-module
```

I would like to mention that when I execute the `git ls-remote https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-module` command manually I get the information of the branches and tags without problems.

I checked [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299355/go-get-a-private-repo-from-codecommit/) but in that case SSH protocol is used instead of HTTP GRC. Maybe the only way to import a module from a private repository is via SSH?

Comment: what is your motivation for using the http-grc protocol? have you actually tried with a .git at the end of the repo-url as suggested in the other question's answers? (for me it works either way, the .git is nor necessary). git config --global url.xxx seems like a mistake, because why would you want this setting for all repos / pprojects?

Comment: In my company we use https-grc for security reasons instead of SSH.
Yes, I'm trying with .git at the end: `go get -x git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-module.git`.
The git config --global seems to be necessary to get repos not using standard HTTPS protocol as I read in another sources. In fact, I can't do go get codecommit::us-west-2://my-module because go get command doesn't allow to use characters like ":"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

**Set Git credential helper:**

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
```

**Set GOPRIVATE env var:**

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

**In MacOS, disable keychain for Git:**

Comment `helper = osxkeychain` in the file containing that value (run `git config -l --show-origin | grep credential` to find the target file)

**Run go get:**

```
go get git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-module.git
```

Comment: you are a saint. Thank you that helped me a lot!