# Go import error: invalid version unknow revision

Tags: go, cilium

[Code, file structure on left and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlw3G.png)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/cilium/cilium/api/v1/models"
    "github.com/cilium/cilium/pkg/client"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting Application...")

    fmt.Println("Terminating Application...")
}
```

This is the error I get when I run: go run main.go

```
github.com/cilium/cilium@1.7.2 requires github.com/optiopay/kafka@v0.0.0-2080809090225-01ce283b732b: ivalid version: unknown revision 01ce283b732b
```

I am using go mod file for my dependencies and my go version is latest 1.14

I also checked my file structure and I already have cilium@v1.7.2 under pkg/mod/github.com/cilium

I tried adding `github.com/optiopay/kafka` under my import statement in my code but i get the same exact error still.

I have no idea how to fix this, I was googling but I could fin no definite or clear answer which worked. Any help appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this error because `replace` directives in `go.mod` are ignored by `go mod`/`go get` and the `go.mod` file of Cilium v1.7.2 contains many replace directives.
To workaround this issue, replicate the replace directives of the version of Cilium that you are trying to import into your own `go.mod` file. An example for Cilium v1.7 can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/cilium/client-examples/tree/master/v1.7).

Answer (score 0):

seems optiopay/kafka is your private repo. You can configure ssh with git. and set your url in git config to use ssh instead of https.

Steps:

1. configure ssh (if not already done)
2. update git config ->
   `git config --system url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`

Comment: for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668444/go-get-private-repo-from-bitbucket/38672481#38672481

Answer (score 0):

**Error** - the version that go is trying to pull for that specific module that imports it is either outdated or invalid.

**Solution** - For example in my case i was getting this error below:

```
go: downloading github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books imports
    github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books/server imports
    github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books: github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: invalid version: unknown revision 000000000000
```

as you can see above my module "github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books/server" imports another module "github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books:" this import throws the error above,  so i go to my go.mod file and make the following changes:

```
 1 module github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books/server                                                                                                           
  2 
  3 go 1.18
  4 
  5 replace github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/db => ../../db
  6 
  7 replace github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books => ../../gen/go/proto/books
  8 
  9 require (
 10   github.com/arangodb/go-driver v1.3.2
 11   github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/db v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
 12   github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books latest
 13   google.golang.org/grpc v1.47.0
 14 )
```

check above in line 12 where i put **"latest"** instead of the version number i.e  "v0.0.0...."

I save the file and then i run  **"go mod tidy"**

The compiler then changes the "latest" designation to an up to date version,i.e it will look as below after running the mod tidy command.

```
1 module github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books/server                                                                                                           
  2 
  3 go 1.18
  4 
  5 replace github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/db => ../../db
  6 
  7 replace github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books => ../../gen/go/proto/books
  8 
  9 require (
 10   github.com/arangodb/go-driver v1.3.2
 11   github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/db v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
 12   github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books v0.0.0-20220601171028-60237b9c9583
 13   google.golang.org/grpc v1.47.0
 14 )
```

PS: check the package where i make the changes, dont change the wrong imports