# Go mod private repo on bitbucket

Tags: go, bitbucket, go-modules

I have a project to do at my job and we're using Bitbucket. So we have all our repos like this :

`bitbucket.org/company/project` Nothing new here.

I have created a repository called go-tools, his module name is `bitbucket.org/company/go-tools` and his path his `bitbucket.org/company/go-tools`

Following this [medium post](https://medium.com/swlh/go-modules-with-private-git-repository-3940b6835727) I could achieve a `go mod tidy`

```golang
package whatever

import (
       "bitbucket.org/company/go-tools"
       "bitbucket.org/company/go-tools/env"
       // and so on ...
)
```

The problem occurs when I try to replace "bitbucket.org/company" by "company.com" because we would like to have our company name instead bitbucket.

So my module name become `company.com/go-tools` instead of `bitbucket.org/company/go-tools`

And my imports become :

```golang
package whatever

import (
       "company.com/go-tools"
       "company.com/go-tools/env"
       // and so on ...
)
```

I have set my GOPRIVATE to use bitbucket and configured git to use bitbucket instead of company.com

```sh
git config --global url."https://{username}:{app password}@bitbucket.com/company".insteadOf "https://company.com"
go env -w GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/company
```

And from there I only get a 404 error telling me that my package can't be found.

Did anyone have an idea why ? Am I misunderstanding something ?

NOTE : I also [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668444/go-get-private-repo-from-bitbucket)

Comment: do you run `go get` with `go mod download` in verbose mode? if yes - can you provide output?

Comment: Hi @OlegButuzov, thanx for your reply

Here are the logs. It seems not even looking at bitbucket

Comment: ?> go env GOPRIVATE
bitbucket.org/company

?> go mod download -x company.com/go-tools@gomodtest
# get https://proxy.golang.org/company.com/go-tools/@v/gomodtest.info
# get https://proxy.golang.org/company.com/go-tools/@v/gomodtest.info: 410 Gone (0.129s)
# get https://company.com/go-tools?go-get=1
# get https://company.com/go-tools?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.784s)
go mod download: company.com/go-tools@gomodtest: unrecognized import path "company.com/go-tools": reading https://company.com/go-tools?go-get=1: 404 Not Found

Comment: Use a `replace` directive in go.mod instead of using a redirect in your git config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @adrian for your reply this answer my question for at least a part.
I was more looking for a way of just go get 'company.com/whatever' but this is ok.

So if I understand correctly I need to `go get bitbucket.org/company/whatever` first and then `go mod edit -replace bitbucket.org/company/whatever=company.com/whatever`

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Atelias. did you find any solution to do ``go get company.com/whatever`` without using replace directive in go.mod ?