# 'go get' from bitbucket with two different bitbucket account

Tags: git, go, ssh, bitbucket, go-get

#1 I followed some articles on how to access github or bitbucket with two different ssh keys, and it works fine when I do a `git clone ...`.  So, I can do a `git clone git://git@github.com/...` and `git clone git://git@mycompany-bitbucket.org/...` without any problem.

#2 I also followed some article on how to use private repository

However, if I combine the two articles (#1 and #2), `go get ...` will always use the `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/...` .  So, is there a way to force `go get ...` to use something like `https://api.mycompany-bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/`?

Comment: Have you tried setting a [`url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) replace rule on your local machine ?

Comment: the more go-ish solution is probably to set up a corporate goproxy (see [`GOPROXY portocol` section in the docs](https://golang.org/ref/mod#goproxy-protocol)), but I don't know of a standard implementation for such a proxy.

Comment: perhaps https://github.com/goproxy/goproxy ?

Comment: try following these 2 steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/62558193/10461720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses. After doing some testing and tinkering, I found out this definitive steps:

In ~/.ssh/config:

```
# Work Bitbucket account
Host work-bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 User git
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa-work

# Work Bitbucket account
Host altssh.work-bitbucket.org
 HostName altssh.bitbucket.org
 User git
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa-work
```

The `work-bitbucket.org` allows you to do 'git clone git@work-bitbucket.org/<account_name>/" and use a custom ssh key

The `altssh.work-bitbucket.org` satisfies the requirement for `go get ...` (with `export GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/<account_name>`)

And also execute:

```
git config --global url."ssh://git@altssh.work-bitbucket.org:443/<account_name>".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/<account_name>"
```

Note about the 'work' prefix