# golang get command with duosecurity

Tags: go, two-factor-authentication

In my company we have our internal git repo that is protected by duosecurity two factor authentication. 
When I try to run this command

```
go get -u git.source.mycompany.com/projects/myproj
```

In the response it redirects me to the twofactor URL.

```
https fetch: Get https://mycompany.com/Redirect/SSO?SReq=fIpehPwuz9NB3%2BkJLJ76dAKSzI6U%2BSnYXnC%2Fbit%2BYJPkOlr8RTujF0F9asMfOufVMjWVkl%2FevKrMx8KCcBATRmjSj%2Fw%2FjeQb&RelayState=ss%3Amem%3A3727673680e6043f2e111
```

Has anyone seen or dealt with two factor when doing go get from terminal.

Comment: Have you seen  this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository)?

Comment: That was a great help. Pointed me in right direction.