# How to install private dependencies in Docker

Tags: docker, go

I am trying to get a Go app inside a docker container. This is my first bigger Go and Docker project. The go program runs just fine as long as I am running it on my local machine, now I want to run it on EC2 within a docker container. My docker file looks like this:

```
FROM golang:latest 
RUN mkdir /tir
ADD . /tir 
WORKDIR /tir
RUN go build -o main . 
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

But I get the following error for every private dependencies:

```
main.go:17:2: cannot find package "github.com/ser/model" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/ser/model (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/ser/model (from $GOPATH)
```

When I insert `RUN go get ./..` before `RUN go build -o main .`, I get the following error for every package:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

package github.com/ser/endpoints: exit status 128

I have tried a couple of solutions, but none worked. I always end up having the above errors. Since this is my first docker + golang project, are there any ready to use dockerfiles for an golang app with public as well as private dependencies?

UPDATE:
I deinstalled go, and copied every file in one by one and used dep -ensure after every file. Now it works, thanks :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to "go get" a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository)

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058056/running-dep-ensure-vendor-only-inside-docker-hangs-not-able-to-pull-private-rep/55761788#55761788

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are probably stored in `GOPATH/src/<import-path>` and you manage them with `go get` tool.

Consider [vendoring](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/)  and tools like [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) or [modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)

As a result your dependencies will be included into source control and project will be much more portable.

You also can improve the way how you create `Docker` image.

Current implementation uses one container that includes whole `GO` toolchain. Code is copied inside that that container, container compiles and hosts the code. Only later is necessary for production.

Better option will be to use 2 containers:

1. Go Tools for compilation
2. Lightweight container that only host binaries

```js
# Debian image with the latest version of Go installed
# and a workspace (GOPATH) configured at /go.
FROM golang:1.11 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/space/project/

# Copy the local package files to the container's workspace.
ADD . /go/src/github.com/space/project/

# Build the service inside the container.
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM centurylink/ca-certs
EXPOSE 8080

# Copy app
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/space/project/app   /
ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]
```

Comment: I tried to use dep, but got the following issue
`1 transitively valid internal packages
 14 external packages imported from 11 projects
(0)   ✓ select (root)
(1)       ← no more versions of github.com/aristotle/auth0 to try; begin backtrack
  ✗ solving failed

Solver wall times by segment:
     b-list-versions: 39.248856824s
               other:   39.136849ms
         select-root:   29.564742ms
            new-atom:     954.931µs
  b-deduce-proj-root:      26.362µs
     b-source-exists:         490ns

  TOTAL: 39.318540198s` ideas ?

Comment: github.com/aristotle/auth0 is not public repository. How did you use it before adding `dep`?

Comment: I just imported it via the path und used in my project like any other package. I have to say I tried to remove all non public packages from my project, but I still get the same error. Fx also for gorilla/mux

Comment: With vendoring, all your dependencies should be stored in `/vendor` folder inside your project local directory and should be committed into source control.

Comment: I deinstalled go, and copied every file in one by one and used dep -ensure after every file. Now it works, thanks :D

Comment: @user1990524 add this comment as `update: ` to your question to help others and mark answer as correct