# Running dep ensure -vendor-only inside Docker Hangs not able to pull private Repos

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, dep, glide-golang

My Dockerfile:

```js
FROM golang:1.11.4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git bash curl -yqq
ENV ENV test
ENV GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
RUN curl -Ls https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/releases/download/v0.12.3/glide-v0.12.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp \
&& mv /tmp/linux-amd64/glide /usr/bin/
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/<Myrepo>/
COPY . $GOPATH/src/github.com/<Myrepo>/
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/<Myrepo>/     
RUN dep ensure -vendor-only
```

When i am building this docker file it hangs at `RUN dep ensure -vendor-only`

It fails to pull the dependencies which are private repos

Is there any possiblities to store git credentials inside Docker or any way to build Docker with one or more private repos of GOlang

Comment: Sounds like a network problem. Lack of credentials wouldn't lead to a hang.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to "go get" a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository)

Comment: running in local suceeds whereas credentials are stored locally

Comment: I'm sure. But that doesn't mean a lack of credentials can cause a hang. This is a networking problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use some thing like this

```
# ensure that the private Github repo is
# accessed using SSH instead of HTTPS
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN echo "$SSH_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN echo '[url "ssh://git@github.com/*your_repo*/"]' >> /root/.gitconfig && echo 'insteadOf = https://github.com/*your_repo*/' >> /root/.gitconfig
```

Refer [this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to add ssh key to your git repo

Comment: we use https mode no ssh method we are using for GIT

Answer (score 0):

Adding **.netrc** file will pass credentials inside the docker containers and help to pull more than one private repository to build dependencies

```
# vim .netrc
  machine github.com
      login < your GitHub token >
```

add those 2 lines and pass your GitHub token

```js
FROM golang:1.11.4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git bash curl -yqq
ENV ENV test
ENV GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
RUN curl -Ls https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/releases/download/v0.12.3/glide-v0.12.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp \
&& mv /tmp/linux-amd64/glide /usr/bin/
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/<Myrepo>/
COPY . $GOPATH/src/github.com/<Myrepo>/
COPY .netrc /root/
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/<Myrepo>/     
RUN dep ensure -vendor-only
```

Alternate way

Store TOKEN in the env variable and while docker runtime pass it to .netrc

```
echo machine github.com login $TOKEN > ~/.netrc
```

```js
FROM golang:1.11.4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git bash curl -yqq
ENV ENV test
ENV GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     
RUN curl -Ls https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/releases/download/v0.12.3/glide-v0.12.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp \
&& mv /tmp/linux-amd64/glide /usr/bin/
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/<Myrepo>/
COPY . $GOPATH/src/github.com/<Myrepo>/
RUN echo machine github.com login $TOKEN > ~/.netrc
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/<Myrepo>/     
RUN dep ensure -vendor-only
```