# How to use local Go module inside a Go project

Tags: go, go-modules

In our local network, we have a GitLab running. The IP is bind to `gitlab.local`. I have a go package `http://gitlab.local/projectsmall/core`, and it is being used by another Go project. Inside this project, when I try to run `go mod tidy`, I am getting this error:

```
go get gitlab.local/projectsmall/core: 
unrecognized import path "gitlab.local/projectsmall/core" 
(https fetch: 
  Get https://gitlab.local/projectsmall/core?go-get=1: 
  dial tcp 192.168.28.9:443: 
  connect: connection refused
)
```

I have added the `id_rsa.pub` contents to SSH Kyes. I tried to add this `core` project to go mod path like this: `/Users/UserA/go/pkg/mod/gitlab.local/guxin/core`. The `import "gitlab.local/guxin/core"` is still red using GoLand IDE. It seems the go mod project can't find this `gitlab.local/guxin/core` package. In `go.mod` file, inside require block, when I added this `gitlab.local/guxin/core`, the IDE alert: `usage: require module/path`.

Comment: although `go get` do not work well with gitlab, but at first you might need to solve the `connection refused` issue

Comment: The first thing to do is getting `curl -v https://gitlab.local/projectsmall/core?go-get=1` to work. This seems to be a networking, connectivity issue unrelated to Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it is using https, but local gitlab is not using SSL. So I tried `go get -v -insecure` and it's working now.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but it seems to me that the problem may be that you are using the ssh keys and you are connecting via the HTTPs protocol as you can see from the error text.

Try it: https://gist.github.com/dmitshur/6927554

```
$ ssh -A vm
$ git config --global url."git@gitlab.local:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.local/"
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[url "git@gitlab.local:"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.local/
$ go get gitlab.local/private/repo && echo Success!
Success!
```

And also:
[What's the proper way to "go get" a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository)

> In GitLab, since the repositories always end in .git, I must specify
>   .git at the end of the repository name to make it work, for example:
>
> `import "example.org/myuser/mygorepo.git"`
>
> And:
>
> `$ go get example.org/myuser/mygorepo.git`
>
> Looks like GitHub solves
>   this by appending ".git".

Comment: If you believe there is a solution at one of those links, include the relevant details in the body of your answer. Links can die over time and this answer would become useless to someone searching for it in the future.