# How do I use the go get command on code commit repositories using ssh auth?

Tags: git, go

I'm new to GO and AWS. I have succesfully followed the instructions here https://github.com/google/battery-historian and been able to get the project running locally. Now I want to host it on our AWS code commit instead as we don't use git. I have created a new repository like this:

```
battery-historian/
    activity
    aggregated
    ...
    setup.go
```

and then tried running the following command;

`go get -d -u ssh://git-codecommit.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/battery-historian/...` from my Linux terminal

I keep getting "invalid char ':". I guess this is because of the ssh protocol. If I run without protocol, I get

```
package git-codecommit.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/battery-historian/...: unrecognized import path "git-codecommit.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/battery-historian" (parse https://git-codecommit.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/battery-historian?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

I have worked with code commit before and only used ssh and it have worked fine. I have modified my .ssh/config file with my amazon User and rsa key.

**How do I use the go get command on code commit repositories using ssh auth?**

I have looked at [What's the proper way to "go get" a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository) but I'm unable to get it working. All examples are for Github. If I clone the repo normally and then run `go get -u` I get

```
-init --recursive
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'third_party/closure-library' in .gitmodules
package github.com/google/battery-historian: exit status 128
```