# How to set GOPRIVATE environment variable

Tags: go, environment-variables, go-modules

I started working on a `Go` project and it uses some private modules from Github private repos and whenever I try to run `go run main.go` it gives me a below `410 Gone` error:

> verifying github.com/repoURL/go-proto@v2.86.0+incompatible/go.mod: github.com/repoURL/go-proto@v2.86.0+incompatible/go.mod: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/!repoURL/go-proto@v2.86.0+incompatible: 410 Gone

I can easily clone private repo from terminal which means my `ssh` keys are configured correctly. I read [here](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_configuration_for_non_public_modules) that I need to set `GOPRIVATE` environment variable but I am not sure how to do that.

Can anyone answer or point to the relevant tutorial?

**Go:** v1.13, **OS:** macOS Mojave

Comment: `man $(basename $SHELL)`

Comment: There's a *go help* for that: `go help module-private`

Comment: Or just to make live easier, `export GOPRIVATE=*`

Comment: That's an excellent question.

Comment: I was gonna ask how to add multiple path when exporting GOPRIVATE. I've tried `export GOPRIVATE="github.com/repo01;gitlab.com/repo02"` but didn't work. But, after looking @Jay 's comment, I tried `export GOPRIVATE=*` and it just works 

Btw, I think the go help for that right now is moving to `go help private`

Comment: @PikoMonde Yep, that works, or use a comma as the separator.

Comment: @PikoMonde as per Jay's comment. The key bit from the doc:

"Comma-separated list of glob patterns"

Comment: The help topic for this is 'go help private' contrary to a comment above.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

```sh
go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/repoURL/private-repo
```

**OR**

If you want to allow all private repos from your organization

```sh
go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/<OrgNameHere>/*
```

---

#### Long Answer:

Check ["Module configuration for non-public modules"](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Configuration_for_downloading_non_public_code) for more information:

> The GOPRIVATE environment variable controls which modules the go command considers to be private (not available publicly) and should therefore not use the proxy or checksum database. The variable is a comma-separated list of glob patterns (in the syntax of Go's path.Match) of module path prefixes. For example,
>
> ```
>  GOPRIVATE=*.corp.example.com,rsc.io/private
> ```
>
> causes the go command to treat as private any module with a path prefix matching either pattern, including git.corp.example.com/xyzzy, rsc.io/private, and rsc.io/private/quux.

.
.

> The 'go env -w' command (see 'go help env') can be used to set these variables for future go command invocations.

---

#### Note on the usage of ssh:

If you use **ssh** to access git repo (locally hosted), you might want to add the following to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```sh
[url "ssh://git@git.local.intranet/"]
       insteadOf = https://git.local.intranet/
```

for the `go` commands to be able to access the git server.

Comment: Thanks! Working now so the trick was to use wildcard url with organization name. `go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/{OrgNameHere}/*`

Comment: Probably easier for people who code primarily with private code `export GOPRIVATE=*`

Comment: Using `export GOPRIVATE=*` assigns all file names in the current directory to GOPRIVATE, which isn't what you want.

Comment: That is an excellent answer. Thank you for that answer. I liked that answer.

Comment: I still like that answer even now and will probably continue to like it for a long time. Maybe years.

Comment: For those of you who are looking for more details as to how `GOPRIVATE` works, etc., [Go Modules Reference](https://golang.org/ref/mod#private-modules) covers a lot more in detail.

Comment: When executing in `zsh` the commands give `zsh: no matches found`. Escape the asterix by writing `\*` so it doesn't expand on it.

Answer (score 28):

If zsh use:

`go env -w GOPRIVATE='gitlab.my_firm_name.com/*'`

otherwise get

`zsh: no matches found: GOPRIVATE=gitlab.my_firm_name.com/*`

Comment: this resolved the error for zsh thanks

Comment: Works for fish shell as well

Answer (score 16):

Just a follow up on the usage of ssh, this is the command used to get it working:

GitHub:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Bitbucket:

```
git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"
```

Answer (score 2):

If zsh use, add a `/` before wildcard like this:
`go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/<OrgNameHere>\/*`