# could not read username when go get a private package

Tags: git, go, go-modules

I have one Go project that use a private library hosted in github. Currently am using go modules, so I configured the access to github via SSH so I could use `go get github.com/myorg/mylibrary` this was working before, but now am getting the next message when I do again `go get github.com/myorg/mylibrary@commitId`:

```
github.com/myorg/mylibrary@v5.2.1-0.20210110224145-108714b2f88c: verifying module: 
github.com/myorg/mylibrary@v5.2.1-0.20210110224145-108714b2f88c: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/!myorg/mylibrary@v5.2.1-0.20210110224145-108714b2f88c: 410 Gone
        server response:
        not found: github.com/myorg/mylibrary@v5.2.1-0.20210110224145-108714b2f88c: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/b186106557bfd44bc932dd151f0fcd2758d8d89d09ab32f8915de7f151e393d1: exit status 128:
                fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I already tried with:

```
env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get github.com/myorg/mylibrary@commitId
```

but still got the same. So, why am getting this? and how could I overcome it?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58306008/11810946) help?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ssh + public key to access github private project with go module

first replace git HTTP scheme to ssh scheme

```
git config -e
// if you want replace scheme with global config use --global
git config --global -e
```

and then add below lines

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
     insteadOf = https://github.com
```

ensure that your public key has been added to github

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
// if file not found use ssh-keygen to generate it 
ssh-keygen
```

add public key to github access below URL add it

```
https://github.com/settings/keys
```

now you can get github private project within go mod