# Golang unable to download private dependencies

Tags: git, go, gitlab, go-modules, go-get

My project have some dependencies on my companies private gitlab repository. They are basically sub modules.

Structure is like as below

```
code.company.com/project/modules/

module1 - git repository
module2 - git repository
module2 - git repository
```

I have configured SSH on gitlab and able to clone module1,2 and 3 on my system.

I have configured go env

```
GOPRIVATE=code.company.com/*
GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
```

I have configured git configuration as below

```
[url "ssh://git@code.company.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://code.company.com/
```

Now, some modules are dependent on each other. So, I have dependency as below.

```
module code.company.com/project/modules/module1

go 1.17

require (
    code.company.com/project/modules/module2 v0.1.0
    code.company.com/project/modules/module3 v0.1.0
)
```

But, when I do go build, I am getting below issue.

```
somepackage\somefile.go:9:2: reading code.company.com/project/modules/module2/module2/go.mod at revision module/v0.1.0: git ls-remote -q origin in C:\***\go\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\640f608ba2ce74aefee0ca7a10bdb3bc54095ae8d5ba700aeb3a063cdf50a7a6: exit status 128:
        ssh: Could not resolve hostname code.company.com:project: Name or service not known
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

I tried everything but unable to download repository. I am getting same issue.
Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Thanks

Comment: Something is probably **not** setup correctly so that you endup with this **hostname**: `code.company.com:project:`.... which leads to a DNS failure, of course: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname code.company.com:project: Name or service not known`

Comment: This url looks fishy: `ssh://git@code.company.com:` (because of the closing colon). I guess it should be `ssh://git@code.company.com`.

Comment: If I setup url to "ssh://git@code.company.com" then getting this issue.
 ssh: Could not resolve hostname code.company.comproject: Name or service not known

Comment: Where does `project` come from? Maybe the problem is there. Perhaps it should be `/project` wherever it is setup?... I am in the blind, by the way. No experience with golang... just making.... _educated(?) guesses_.

Comment: If I remove url configuration from gitconfig, then I am getting this issue
 fatal: repository 'https://code.company.com/project/modules.git/' not found
but modules is not a git project. I don't know how this .git is keep on adding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305567/how-to-set-goprivate-environment-variable