# Is there a way to import go modules from private repository using bazel

Tags: go, bazel, goland, bazel-rules

I have a go project which is managed using bazel. I want to add external dependency from a private repository.
I am able to add the packages from the public repository using the `go_repository` construct:

```
go_repository(
    name = "com_github_pkg_errors",
    commit = "816c9085562cd7ee03e7f8188a1cfd942858cded",
    importpath = "github.com/pkg/errors",
)
```

But if use the same thing for private repo, the module fetch is failing

```
Error in download_and_extract: java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/<my-private-repo>/<my-package>/archive/refs/tags/v1.0.0.zip] to /private/var/tmp/_bazel_Mahima.Gupta/34cbf2084d2922d4b41317a7d830e0a8/external/<target-name>/temp8433105752417763970/v1.0.0.zip: GET returned 404 Not Found
```

Is there a way to fetch modules from some private repo?

Comment: I originally thought of this as a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305567/how-to-set-goprivate-environment-variable but now I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

To set Bazel configuration options Create a .bazelrc file.

Add your private repository credentials in the .bazelrc file, you can specify the credentials needed to access your private repository.

Specify the go_repository for your private package, Use the go_repository construct as you did for public packages, but this time for your private repository. Make sure to provide the full URL to your private repository, including the authentication token if required.

Update your BUILD file, you can now specify the dependency on your private package using the name you defined in the go_repository construct.
Make sure visibility is public.
`visibility = ["//visibility:public"]`