# What's the difference between export and "go env -w"

Tags: go, configuration, environment-variables

What exactly does "`go env -w`" do? I've went through this [long proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30411) but haven't figured out the gist of it. I.e.,

- will it be writing such setting anywhere in Go related configure files?
- what if I just simply use `export`, What's the difference between the two methods?
- If I use "go env -w", how to unset it later on if I don't need it any more?

BTW, it is the "[go env -w GOPRIVATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305567/how-to-set-goprivate-environment-variable)" that I'm asking about. What would be the differences if I do either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `go help environment`:

> The go command and the tools it invokes consult environment variables for configuration. If an environment variable is unset or empty, the go command uses a sensible default setting. To see the effective setting of the variable , run `go env <NAME>`. To change the default setting, run `go env -w <NAME>=<VALUE>`.
>
> **Defaults changed using `go env -w` are recorded in a Go environment configuration file stored in the
> per-user configuration directory, as reported by `os.UserConfigDir`.**
>
> The location of the configuration file can be changed by setting
> the environment variable `GOENV`, and `go env GOENV` prints the
> effective location, but `go env -w` cannot change the default location. See `go help env` for details.

Environment variables take precedence. So if you have `GOPRIVATE` set in your system, that will be used. If not, or if you unset it, the value you set with `go env -w GOPRIVATE=xy` will be used.

And if you run `go help env`:

> The `-u` flag requires one or more arguments and unsets the default setting for the named environment variables, if one has been set with `go env -w`.

So you can unset the manually changed `GOPRIVATE` default by running `go env -u GOPRIVATE`.