# How to use the go get command to download private projects from the company's gitlab repository

Tags: git, go, gitlab, go-get

I have a project that needs to rely on the internal gitlab private library.

I configured it through the following command, but a URL 404 error occurred. The example is as follows

```bash
$ go env -w GOPRIVATE=a.b.com
$ go env -w GOINSECURE=a.b.com
$ go get -v -x a.b.com/testgroup/compkg
# get https://a.b.com/?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.044s)
# get https://a.b.com/?go-get=1: 403 Forbidden (0.044s)
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.044s)
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.001s)
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.001s)
# get https://a.b.com/?go-get=1: 403 Forbidden (0.002s)
go get: unrecognized import path "a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg": reading https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1: 404 Not Found
```

Then I tried to switch to ssh to pull, the example is as follows

```bash
$ git config --global url."git@a.b.com:testgroup/compkg.git".insteadOf "https://a.b.com/testgroup/compkg"
$ go get -v -x a.b.com/testgroup/compkg
# get https://a.b.com/?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.044s)
# get https://a.b.com/?go-get=1: 403 Forbidden (0.044s)
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.044s)
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/?go-get=1
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.001s)
# get https://a.b.com/testgroup?go-get=1: 404 Not Found (0.001s)
# get https://a.b.com/?go-get=1: 403 Forbidden (0.002s)
go get: unrecognized import path "a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg": reading https://a.b.com/testgroup/testpkg?go-get=1: 404 Not Found
```

Same error on both attempts. **go get: unrecognize import path "a.b.com/testgroup/compkg": reading `https://a.b.com/testgroup/compkg?go-get=1`: 404 Not Found**

I used the following curl command to return the following error:

```bash
$ curl --insecure https://a.b.com/testgroup/compkg?go-get=1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>404 Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.<hr/>Powered by Tengine</body>
</html
```

Is there any other way to try, or is it my trial and error? Looking forward to your reply.

> PS: a.b.com/test/compkg does not have any git **tag** And `testgroup` is groupname not username of gitlab.

- gitlab version: Gitlab Community Edition 13.6.7
- go version: go v1.16
- I can `git pull` project by enter username and password

Comment: First of all: Update Go. Yours is outdated. Try again. And: Your Gitlab is 3 years old too. Basically everything looks sensible and _should_ work (unless e.g. turned of in your Gitlab setting)

Comment: "404 Not Found" almost certainly indicates that you're not authorized (to avoid repo enumeration by unauth'd parties).  "Same error on both attempts... `reading https://`" your configuration to use ssh didn't work; it still used https.  Use ssh for this; `go get` doesn't support providing username / password.  Add a key to your ssh agent, put it in default place, or otherwise configure ssh for a.b.com.  If `git pull` works without user/password prompts, `go get` should too

Comment: @erik258 I setting ssh-keys for gitlab and `git pull` work without password, but `go get` astill has the same error. I added some parameters to show the details when go get. I added them in the original text. Could you please see if you can locate the problem?

Comment: OH - have you done this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305567/how-to-set-goprivate-environment-variable

Comment: @erik258 yes, I set GOPRIVATE and url insteadOf, But the error is still exactly the same as in the question