# Why `go get` tries to access http instead of https?

Tags: git, go

I'm now using private repository for my collaboration projects.
I set up my personal GitLab like `gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget`,
and I tried to provide it for my team.
(the repository `https://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget` is public for this question)

### Problems

However, when I tried `go get -v gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget`,
it says

```
get "gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git"} at //gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget?go-get=1
package gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget: cannot download, http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git uses insecure protocol
```

Also, I tried `go get -v gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git` with explicit `.git` suffix
And I get

```
# cd .; git ls-remote https://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget/' not found
# cd .; git ls-remote git+ssh://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget
```

you can see `go get` tries `https` first,
but `go get` strip suffix of `.git` therefore it says the repository not found, and advance to next `git+ssh` protocol. 
I could get `git clone gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git` without any authentication process,

```
git ls-remote https://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git
c238e4b9818eabe6309a2c5cf274808ec39bf7d5        HEAD
c238e4b9818eabe6309a2c5cf274808ec39bf7d5        refs/heads/master
```

### My Incomplete Solution

After I set global git redirection configuration (like `git config --global url."https://gitlab.xity.dev".insteadOf "http://gitlab.xity.dev"`)
I could get the package with `-insecure` flag

```
$ go get -v -insecure gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget
get "gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git"} at //gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget?go-get=1
gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget (download)
gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget
```

When I does not provide `http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget` like

```
$ curl -I http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.16.0
Date: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 06:16:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive
$ curl -I http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.16.0
Date: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 06:17:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive
$ git clone http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget
Cloning into 'testgoget'...
fatal: repository 'http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget/' not found
$ git clone http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git
Cloning into 'testgoget'...
fatal: repository 'http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git/' not found
```

Yes, this may work because `go get` uses `git clone`, and `go get` adds `.git` suffix to given url when the protocol is insecure.

### Other solutions

I could solve this by using `git clone` it at `%GOPATH%/src` manually.

However, this is not my personal project, but collaborative project.
Therefore, I can't tell everyone to do it above. (because me and everyone else are Golang beginners)
I want to using this only with regular Golang manner 
* only with `import "gitlab.xity.dev/XXX/YYY"`. (`import "gitlab.xity.dev/XXX/YYY.git"` also seems to be bad manner for Golang), 
* not manual git redirection configuration and `go get -insecure` by oneself

### Questions

#### 1. How can I help `go get` to access `https` instead of `http`?

I've surveyed many helps like Q&A like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository), and add global git configuration like

```
[url "https://gitlab.xity.dev"]
        insteadOf = http://gitlab.xity.dev
```

but this does not help `go get` properly without `-insecure` flag.
I understand that `go get` never realize that there is such git configuration.

Then, How can I help `go get` to prefer trying `https` instead of `http`?

#### 2. Why `go get` prefer to access `http` instead of `https` even it says it does not like to access insecure protocol?

Even `go get` complains about insecure protocol, why it does not try to access `https` at first instead of `http`?
I'm not sure that this is bug of `go get` or not.

#### 3. Why `go get` strip the suffix `.git` even I give it explicitly?

When I give `.git` suffix explicitly, `go get` drops given suffix and says that it couldn't found repository properly.

```
$ go get -v gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git
# cd .; git ls-remote https://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget/' not found
```

But you can see that `go get` does not need explicit `.git` when it tries insecure protocol like

```
$ go get -v gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget
get "gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git"} at //gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget?go-get=1
package gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget: cannot download, http://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget.git uses insecure protocol
```

What makes the difference?

### Conditions & Environment

I tried this with 
* go version go1.14.4 windows/amd64
* go version go1.14.3 darwin/amd64
* go version go1.12.7 linux/amd64
* go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64

I've set `GOPRIVATE` for `gitlab.xity.dev` like

```
go env
...
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GONOPROXY=gitlab.xity.dev
set GONOSUMDB=gitlab.xity.dev
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=t:\go
set GOPRIVATE=gitlab.xity.dev
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
...
```

I think that `GOPRIVATE` is not used yet in this situation.

Comment: It uses http because https://gitlab.xity.dev/QuietJoon/testgoget?go-get=1 tells it to (note the query parameter). Our private Gitlab instance doesn't do this, so this is probably a Gitlab configuration issue.

Comment: ＠Peter Thanks for your accurate answer. I had some problem with my Gitlab configuration, but I didn't realized that the configuration issue could affect to this problem.