# "go get" private github repository using two factor authentication

Tags: go, go-modules

Our private  organization GitHub account is authenticated via

1. Two-factor authentication
2. Personal access token

When I am trying to get go module via `go get` which is in the private organization Github

```
unrecognized import path "<repo>/api?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ()
```

I found a similar thread but the solution didn't work for me

[What's the proper way to "go get" a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository)

Also, I found https://medium.com/@dayakar88/a-guide-to-solve-no-go-import-meta-tags-for-private-repositories-with-go-modules-6b9237f9c9f seems proper solution for my case but I can't understand the solution

Answer (score 3):

I've accomplished this by setting up the [go for non-public modules](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_configuration_for_non_public_modules) passing the Github account as the value.

And by configuring the proxy to fetch it [directly](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_downloading_and_verification).

Optionally, you can force the go get command to use the Github personal access token in the URL ou the SSH (if you let the http:// will fail, since it'll not have access to the repository)

```
EXPORT GOPRIVATE=github.com/YOURACCOUNT && \
EXPORT GOPROXY=direct && \
git config --global url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf https://github.com/
```

Comment: `https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/` are you sure we only token here? i

Comment: Only the token is required, you can optionally add your github username

Comment: I have tried the following way
```export  GOPRIVATE=github.developer.allianz.io/<my-account-name>
export GOPROXY=direct
go get -u <pkgname>```

But still the same error

Comment: You have to define the Github token in the URL, otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: Hopefully google picks this up... This is what I needed to add to my Github Action to ensure `go get` would work during `go build` and `go test`. I added the env vars as noted, and then did `run: git config --global --add url."https://${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}@github.com/".insteadOf https://github.com/` where MY_TOKEN is a personal access token that has repo permissions and has access to my org's private repos. This solves `fatal: could not read username`