# Go get private bitbucket repo giving 403 forbidden

Tags: go, go-get

On execution of
`go get bitbucket.org/../..`

I get this error

```
yash.jain projectname % go get bitbucket.org/../..
go: bitbucket.org/../..
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/../..?fields=scm: 403 Forbidden
go: error loading module requirements
```

**What I tried**

- Setup the ssh key (Working as expected, tested by pushing and pulling the code)
- Set the go env variables to this:

  ```
   GOPRIVATE=""
   GOPROXY="direct"
   GOSUMDB="off"
  ```
- .gitconfig looks like this

  ```
   [url "git@bitbucket.org:"]
       insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
   [user]
       email = yash.jain@company.in
       name = yashjain
  ```
- Added keys to ssh-agent

  ```
   ssh-add -l
   ssh-add -k
  ```
- .ssh/config file looks like this

  ```
   Host bitbucket.org
     HostName bitbucket.org
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
     UseKeychain yes
     StrictHostKeyChecking no
  ```

Still, I get the same error.
Please let me know If I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you tried use `GOPRIVATE=*.bitbucket.org` ?

Comment: Yes I tried this as well. But get same error.

Comment: I still belive its misconfiguration, try `git config --global url."git@bitbucket.<YOUR-COMPANY>".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/<YOUR-COMPANY>"` and `export GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/<YOUR-COMPANY>`

Comment: This is also not working

Comment: does your project name have space or some special characters? As I remember it caused some problems

Comment: No, the project name does not have any space or special character. It's just a single work project name @Vrangz

Comment: I'm also using external repo and in my config there is `[url "https://<company>:<sshKey>@<projectUrl>/_git/]" \n insteadOf = <repoUrl>`
Maybe go this way using https using sshKey after `:` and before `@`

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? @yashjain12yj

Comment: Check if you have a .netrc file with wrong password at home directory

Comment: @ArunaHerath That would apply to https URLs, but this configuration is made to use SSH URLs only.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks.

Comment: Also try https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-run-go-get-on-a-private-repo/qaq-p/1385040 (did you restart ssh-agent)?

Answer (score 6):

These are the steps I tried to make it work.

1. Setup SSH key and connect to bitbucket. I used sourcetree gui by bitbucket to connect using `ssh`.
2. Set the `GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/<orgname>/*`

`*` is to allow all the repo of the org.

After these 2 steps I am able to import the package.

> Note: Sourcetree is only available to Mac and Windows.

Using Commnd Line: For Linux/Mac/Windows:

1. `git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"`
2. Set the `GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/<orgname>/*`

---

**Update**
You might receive the `404` error even after above configuration.

```
Error
reading https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/xyz/privaterepo?fields=scm: 404 Not Found
```

Bitbucket recently update their APIs for private repository and due to which certain golang version breaks.

> Users who do not have access to a private repository will receive 404 (not found) response codes instead of 403 (forbidden) response codes to mask the existence of a private repository at a given URL path.
> Rolling out these changes will break previous versions of Go due to the fact that the go command relies on a 403 response to fetch repositories hosted on Bitbucket Cloud.
> To ensure that you will not run into any issues, update GoLang to the latest version.
>
> 1. Ensure you are on a supported version of GoLang: 1.18, 1.17, or 1.16.
> 2. If you are using 1.17 or 1.16, ensure you are on the latest patch (1.17.7 or 1.16.14)

This will be in effect from June 1st 2022.

[Changes to Bitbucket API Requires Latest Version of Go](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Changes-to-Bitbucket-API-Requires-Latest-Version-of-Go/ba-p/1975819)

Answer (score 4):

There are Two ways I normally resolve this. But, for this you need to configure bitbucket with SSH.

**1. Edit git.config**

edit the global `.gitconfig`

`nano /home/user/.gitconfig`

add following lines

```
[url "git@bitbucket.org:"] insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
```

**2. Export GOPRIVATE**

```
export GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/<your repo>
```

Comment: Thanks @nipuna for the answer. It worked but there are a few more things needs to be done. git config is not required in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Check first what `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` returns, specifically the user mentioned in the Welcome message: it could be an account, which does not have access to the private repository.

As mentioned in "[What's the proper way to “go get” a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61632549/6309)", try also with a private ssh key *not* protected by a passphrase, to make sure there is no prompt for said passphrase in the middle of the `go get` process.

Comment: The `ssh` already configured and yet was unable to get it.

Comment: @ShubhamChadokar Is the private key protected by a passphrase?

Comment: Yes it is protected.

Comment: @ShubhamChadokar Can you try, for testing, with a non-protected private key?

Comment: I tried but it is not working for that also.

Comment: The another answer by nipona worked. I have to set GOPRIVATE variable

Comment: @ShubhamChadokar Great! What other things needed to be done in addition of setting `GOPRIVATE` ?

Comment: Yes. Just added a new answer. Check it out. I added the steps I took.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it via Sourcetree as well. follow the steps below:

1. Download and install Sourcetree
2. configure your bitbucket ssh key in Sourcetree inside connection
3. You will be able to see your account in accounts section. Something like below

[image: source tree account added]

5. Next step is to add your `GOPRIVATE` env variable
6. for that run this command

`go env -w GOPRIVATE="bitbucket.org/<repo>/*"`