# Go Get Private Bitbucket Package

Tags: go, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to `go get` a private Bitbucket package. But when doing so, I receive the following error message:

```
go: bitbucket.org/project/package: reading https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/project/package?fields=scm: 403 Forbidden
    server response: Access denied. You must have write or admin access.
```

I tried to set `git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"`, in combination with `go env -w GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/project`. but that didn't work.

So I tried setting `git config --system url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"`. that didn't work either.

Finally I tried setting GOPRIVATE manually by writing `export GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/project` in `~/.bashrc`. didn't work.

Important to know that I've confirmed that SSH is working correctly by pulling/pushing code from/to private repos.

Comment: Have a look at this thread [go get - 403 SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791976/go-get-private-bitbucket-repo-giving-403-forbidden). It might give a clue.

Comment: When you say “that didn't work” — what commands did you run, and what errors did you see from those commands?