# Access denied when using go get

Tags: mysql, go

I was using `go get` go get the go-sql-driver from github. When I ran the command `go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` as prompted by the [repo](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql), I encountered an error saying "access is denied":

```
go: writing stat cache: mkdir C:\Program Files\GoPath\pkg: Access is denied.
go: downloading github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.5.0
go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: mkdir C:\Program Files\GoPath\pkg: Access is denied.
```

I am using Windows 10. This happened when I changed the `%GOPATH%` environment variable. Any suggestions on solving this?

---

It seems like Go doesn't have the right to access the "Program Files" folder. I created a GoPath folder at another place and `go get`  seemed to work. However, it created a folder named "pkg" in "GoPath", but from the compilation file I am having, it looks like the package should be installed under an "src" folder. Could somebody please explain how this happened?

Comment: I had a similar problem on Mac and the solution was to export these variables `GO111MODULE=on` `GOPROXY=direct` `GOSUMDB=off`. This solved my problem, but  you may still have other problems. In which case check through this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mkdir C:\Program Files\GoPath\pkg: Access is denied.
```

It looks like access denied while trying to create directory. Either change the installation directory or grant access to the path mentioned.

If it is your development machine or laptop, open `Command Prompt as administrator` and try installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a specific IDE run the IDE as administrator.