# "go get" fails to download a go package, git repository hosted on a Github Entreprise (behind VPN)

Tags: git, go, github, github-enterprise

I'm trying to download a Go package that is on an Entreprise Github.

Noteworthy, the domain is not visible outside the VPN, however I'm connected to that VPN.

I can browse to `https://github.mydomain.com/some_repository` with a browser, however I need to login.

```
$ go get -v github.mydomain.com/some_repository

get "github.mydomain.com/some_repository": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"github.mydomain.com/some_repository", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.mydomain.com/some_repository.git"} at //github.mydomain.com/some_repository?go-get=1
go: downloading github.mydomain.com/some_repository v0.0.0
go get github.mydomain.com/some_repository: github.mydomain.com/some_repository@v0.0.0: verifying module: github.mydomain.com/some_repository@v0.0.0: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.mydomain.com/some_repository@v0.0.0: 410 Gone
        server response: not found: github.mydomain.com/some_repository@v0.0.0: unrecognized import path "github.mydomain.com/some_repository": https fetch: Get "https://github.mydomain.com/some_repository?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup github.mydomain.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

I initially thought this was due to the command line tools not having the access token, since the browser can access but not `go get`. I've generated a token on the Entreprise Github, and tried to resolve this problem via:

```
git config --local http.extraheader "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>"
git config --local url."git@github.mydomain.com:".insteadOf "https://github.mydomain.com/"
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45936697/4333266) but that did not help.

The presence of `lookup github.mydomain.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host` could be a clue, since 8.8.8.8 is google's DNS and that can't possibly work since mydomain.com only exists on the VPN. If one disconnects from VPN that mydomain.com does not exist. I'm not sure why `go get` would use 8.8.8.8 as a DNS though.

`scutil --dns | grep 'nameserver\[[0-9]*\]'` lists several DNS servers, none of which is 8.8.8.8, so perhaps `go get` hardcodes it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears setting environment variable `GOPRIVATE=*.mydomain.com` resolves this problem.

Comment: Just a note for the uninitiated that you need to include "export" in that environment variable setting, i.e. `export GOPRIVATE=*.mydomain.com`

Comment: In case of gitlab, `GOPRIVATE=gitlab.mydomain.com/* go get ...` worked for me