# Go get errors "could not read from remote repository"

Tags: go-get

Using "go get", I enter this command:

```
 go get github.com/company/code
```

The repository is private. The error that comes back says this:

```
 go get: module github.com/company/code: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/myusername/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/d3459c3c5732de488c7de6ddbb96dcbb5d3c220735157c316a37c431326e9181: exit status 128:
fatal: 'git@github.comcompany/code' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Note on the first "fatal" line that the URL location does not have a colon between .com and company. I don't know whether that's significant. If it is significant, I don't know where to go to change it. I'd appreciate any tips!

If I ask git to list the remotes, I get

```
$git remote -v
 origin git@github.com:Company/code.git (fetch)
 origin git@github.com:Company/code.git (push)
```

If I push using git ...

```
$git push
everything up-to-date
```

Any ideas? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems like an issue with a private repository. Check this question if it help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository

Answer (score 0):

For private repository you could try the following path **GitLab works as well**:

1. put your PR url as GOPRIVATE: `go env -w GOPRIVATE=https://github.com/subfolder/*`
2. create your personal token
3. edit (or create if it doesn't exist yet) ~/.netrc file, it should look like:

---

```
machine github.com
  login __YOUR_LOGIN__
  password __YOUR_PERSONAL_TOKEN__
```

### error status 128 fix

if after successfully getting private package you have

```
go: __YOUR_MODULE__: verifying module: __YOUR_MODULE__: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/__YOUR_MODULE__: 404 Not Found
        server response:
        not found: __YOUR_MODULE__: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/...: exit status 128:
                fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
        Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
        If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

You should switch off the sumdb support: `go env -w GONOSUMDB="github.com/subfolder/*"`

Hope it helps!