# go get url from github on my Apple MAC is not working on a private repository in company

Tags: go

I'm on a Apple MAC Laptop, `go get` command is not working.
I have normal git access, I can git clone and git commit and git push. Why does this go get command not work?

```
temp % go get github.com/MYCOMPANY/myproject
go get: module github.com/MYCOMPANY/myproject: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/someuser/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/1872293eea4df8de643499713e2d8621a72624bb2514a7a88c1182d1869ef891: exit status 128:
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:MYCOMPANY: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
temp % go get github.com/MYCOMPANY/myproject
go get: module github.com/MYCOMPANY/myproject: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/someuser/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/1872293eea4df8de643499713e2d8621a72624bb2514a7a88c1182d1869ef891: exit status 128:
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:MYCOMPANY: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the proper way to "go get" a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository)

Comment: Check the GOPRIVATE variable (`GOPRIVATE=github.com/MYCOMPANY/*`)
and the git/config for:
```bash
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```
The changes are required when working with private repos.

Answer (score 4):

This is what works for me, based on @elulcao

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/COMPANYNAME
git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Then I can do

```
go mod download
```

In the projects git folder or `go get`

Answer (score -1):

'go get' by default does not support private repositories. It only supports public repos.

If you want to get private repos please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500861/whats-the-proper-way-to-go-get-a-private-repository)

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate rather than posting an answer that links to another SO answer.