# go.mod errors: exit status 128, connection reset by peer

Tags: git, go, gitlab

I cloned the repository onto my PC with SSH. I got an error on the first line of the `go.mod` file. The line is similar to this: `module: gitlab.com/mycorporation/mycompany/susrepo`

The error I got when trying to run `go mod tidy` is:

```
go: gitlab.com/mycorporation/mycompany/dat/go-kafkautil@v0.0.3: reading gitlab.com/mycorporation/mycompany/dat/go-kafkautil.git/go.mod at revision v0.0.3: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/sususer/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/9572610d568gv0dca638cbb8aaf8843db7465c89ce962998ae8516eb93beb2e3: exit status 128:
        fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
go: downloading gitlab.com/mycorporation/mycompany/dat/go-kafkautil.git v0.0.3
go: gitlab.com/mycorporation/mycompany/dat/go-kafkautil@v0.0.3: reading gitlab.com/mycorporation/mycompany/dat/go-kafkautil.git/go.mod at revision v0.0.3: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/sususer/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/9572610d568gv0dca638cbb8aaf8843db7465c89ce962998ae8516eb93beb2e3: exit status 128:
        fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
```

Even when I did not run run `go mod tidy`, pointing the cursor to the mentioned first line gives similar error, with these additional text at the beginning: `err: exit status 1: stderr:`

Comment: Connection reset by peer means that it cannot reach the given host. There might be a firewall in the way blocking access. Check with your local IT.

Answer (score -1):

Check what `git ls-remote -v origin` returns in `gitlab.com/mycorporation/mycompany/dat/go-kafkautil.git` in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`, or `$HOME/go/pkg/mod`.

Depending on the URL, you might have to switch from SSH to HTTPS or vice versa, as illustrated in "[What's the proper way to "`go get`" a private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45936697/6309)"

For instance:

```
git config --global url."git@gitlab.mycompany.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.mycompany.com/"
# or
git config --global url."https://gitlab.mycompany.com/".insteadOf "git@gitlab.mycompany.com:"
```