# Trouble downloading a go module as private repo to be used in other modules

Tags: go

I'm having trouble downloading a private repo:

Here is the structure of my backend:

```
/backend
  /lib
   go.mod

  /serviceA
   go.mod

  /serviceB
   go.mod

  go.work
  go.work.sum
```

I'm having trouble downloading the package github.com/XXX/lib into either serviceA or serviceB packages.

The error I receive:

```
go: module github.com/XXX/lib: git ls-remote -q origin in /Users/XXX/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3d48bbee58603e5a60795e264deda7fec8cd31854e689825028f9ab9f9bbabc2: exit status 128:
    ERROR: Repository not found.
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

The following actions have been done:

I added this to .gitconfig file:

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Also added this to go env GOPRIVATE

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE="github.com/XXX/*"
```

I'm currently stomped as to why I can't download the lib package to be used in either serviceA or serviceB.

Also I should mention, the github.com/XXXX/lib module is already pushed to the main/master branch.

Comment: can you try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501039/5596671

Comment: @BorisBRESCIANI I have tried to follow the link but still failing to download the module.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, make sure that you are able to clone the private repository `github.com/XXXX/lib` on a terminal prompt with the correct SSH configuration.

If you are not able to clone it on a terminal prompt, then generate a pair of public and private keys like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "<comment>"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): sample_id
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in sample_id
Your public key has been saved in sample_id.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:ixzicWEePA55n+QnxUfo/M5T7qDcJd864tZILcqzkPM <comment>
```

Add the generated public key to your GitHub account and then try to clone the private repository again.

If you are not able to clone the repository, you may need to revisit the SSH URL in .gitconfig, and your access rights.

If you are able to clone the private repo after this/already then set the GOPRIVATE environment variable to make your life easier:

```
export GOPRIVATE=*
```

After this, `go get github.com/private/lib` should work fine.

Comment: so I did all you mentioned but still running into the same error. I should mention its in a monorepo.

Comment: @user2738145 Try exporting `GOPRIVATE` like this:
`export GOPRIVATE="github.com/YOUR_PRIVATE_REPO_USER_NAME/*"`