# go version command shows old version number after update to 1.8

Tags: macos, go, upgrade

Pretty much the title. I downloaded/installed Go 1.8 for OS X, but when I go

```
$ go version
go version go1.7.5 darwin/amd64
```

My .bashrc look like the following

```
# some exports omitted

NPM_PACKAGES=/Users/<me>/.npm-packages
NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"

export PATH=~/Library/Python/3.4/bin:$PATH

export GOPATH=$HOME/Go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

My workspace is in a directory called "Go" in my home folder.

What I have checked so far:

- I've checked the files in /usr/local/go/bin, and the VERSION file states "1.8", so I know the installation was successful.
- I have also renewed my terminal session, I even rebooted my pc to make sure no other processes were interfering with it.
- I use Webstorm as my IDE, and it correctly recognized 1.8 as the working version
- It's not a bug in the version number itself, as I can't use the "NextResultSet()" sql functionality, introduced in version 1.8

I believe the culprit might be a wrong configuration in the .bashrc file above, as only the terminal is stuck on the old version, but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Execute `which go`, and you'll see where your old Go resides. Remove it (and references to it).

Comment: Oh, I see now! I removed the go folder from usr/local, and the go file in usr/local/bin and it is now showing correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You obviously have an old version of Go installed, else you couldn't see `go version go1.7.5 darwin/amd64` as the output of `go version`.

IDEs might have more advanced method of detecting Go installations other that simply scanning `PATH` and `GOROOT` (and that's why your IDE found and suggested the newer Go 1.8).

Execute `which go`, and you'll see where your old Go resides. Remove it (and references to it).

Note that in your `.bashrc` you're appending the proper Go `bin` folder to the *end* of `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Which means if `PATH` contains the `bin` folder of the old Go installation (very likely), that is used to execute the `go` command.

Answer (score 48):

I had the same issue.  Even after installing golang 1.10 on mac through download from golang website, mac terminal still showed 1.7 version.

Updating golang through homebrew fixed my issue.

```
brew update
brew upgrade golang
```

Comment: +1 - I found that even though I originally installed golang via the .pkg from their website, my /usr/local/bin/go pointed to the brew installation of golang after running `brew install dep` for another project.

Comment: This works best. Brew should know where did you exacly installed go and go binary files.

Comment: +1 - If `which go` prints `/opt/homebrew/bin/go` then you need to upgrade via homebrew, can't use the download from Go's website.

Comment: This is because you installed `go` with brew. Another way is to uninstalled `go` from brew and try again. But if it's a dependency of another formulae e.g. `golangci-lint` just continue updating with brew..

Answer (score 18):

I manually deleted the old go version by going to the /usr/local/bin folder.

1. First check the path for old go version: 
   `which go`
2. Open the folder containing the go file: 
   `open /usr/local/bin`
3. Delete the go file.

Check the version now, it'll show the updated version.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I had to replace binary files manually after re-installation.

```
cp /usr/local/go/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: This did the job for me. 

Comment: Same. I wonder why this isn't something that automatically happens.

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR**
I've resolved my problem by moving link to go binary from installation folder to `/usr/bin/go`

---

**Step by step:**

1. find go binary:

   ```
   $which go
   /usr/bin/go
   ```
2. create symlinks:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/local/go/bin/go go
   ln -s /usr/local/go/bin/godoc godoc
   ln -s /usr/local/go/bin/gofmt gofmt
   ```
3. copy those 3 symlinks to `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest version from https://golang.org/doc/install
That will replace the one in the default path which is /usr/local/go/bin/go for mac and doesn't require any manual changes to ~/.bashrc/ ~/.bash_profile on mac unless the default path was never set.