# Local packages are not detected by goimports

Tags: go, package, goimports

I have a few packages in separate folders for my golang project that is getting a bit big. I've been trying to create separate packages but don't get detected by goimports

```
GOPATH="/home/malek/go:/home/malek/Desktop/Workspace"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

My directory is as such,

```
Workspace -> src -> application -> utility -> math.go
```

and in my math.go folder, I have package utility

But when I try to do `import "application/utility"` or when i try to include a public function from the math.go file in my main.go file (in application folder), I get undefined...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have 2 parts in your GOPATH, what is “Workspace”? Also don’t set GOROOT.

Comment: Also, if “application/utility” is a proper package, you should be able to run `go build application/utility` without error, or it may provide some information about the problem with your configuration.

Comment: @JimB It builds without a message or error

Comment: @JimB: From the context, the `GOROOT` value in the question looks like part of the output from `go env`. If GOROOT is not set (I don't set it), the Go tool chain sets it to the implicit GOROOT for the `go` command. I have `$ echo $GOROOT\n\n` and `$ go env GOROOT\n/home/peter/go\n`.

Comment: @Whiteclaws: then you need to create a [mcve], since it should work if everything is configured in a standard manner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go build: "Cannot find package" (even though GOPATH is set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214029/go-build-cannot-find-package-even-though-gopath-is-set)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided us with specific steps to reproduce your problem. I don't see a problem. `goimports -w main.go` works. For example,

`application/main.go` before `goimports -w main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(utility.PiE())
}
```

`application/utility/math.go`:

```
package utility

import "math"

func PiE() float64 { return math.Pi * math.E }
```

Commands:

```
#
cd $HOME
cd $HOME/Desktop/Workspace
rm -f src/application/application
cp src/application/main.bak src/application/main.go
tree
cd $HOME/Desktop/Workspace/src/
cat application/utility/math.go
cd application
export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath:$HOME/Desktop/Workspace
go env GOPATH
cat main.go
go build -a
goimports -w main.go
cat main.go
go build -a && ./application
#
```

Output:

```
~$ #
~$ cd $HOME
~$ cd $HOME/Desktop/Workspace
~/Desktop/Workspace$ rm -f src/application/application
~/Desktop/Workspace$ cp src/application/main.bak src/application/main.go
~/Desktop/Workspace$ tree
.
└── src
    └── application
        ├── main.bak
        ├── main.go
        └── utility
            └── math.go

3 directories, 3 files
~/Desktop/Workspace$ cd $HOME/Desktop/Workspace/src/
~/Desktop/Workspace/src$ cat application/utility/math.go
package utility

import "math"

func PiE() float64 { return math.Pi * math.E }
~/Desktop/Workspace/src$ cd application
~/Desktop/Workspace/src/application$ export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath:$HOME/Desktop/Workspace
~/Desktop/Workspace/src/application$ go env GOPATH
/home/peter/gopath:/home/peter/Desktop/Workspace
~/Desktop/Workspace/src/application$ cat main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(utility.PiE())
}
~/Desktop/Workspace/src/application$ go build -a
# application
./main.go:8:14: undefined: utility
~/Desktop/Workspace/src/application$ goimports -w main.go
~/Desktop/Workspace/src/application$ cat main.go
package main

import (
    "application/utility"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(utility.PiE())
}
~/Desktop/Workspace/src/application$ go build -a && ./application
8.539734222673568
~/Desktop/Workspace/src/application$ #
```

`application/main.go` after `goimports -w main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "application/utility"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(utility.PiE())
}
```

Comment: I reproduced your example with a simple application: https://pastebin.com/NagedTLK

Comment: Oh, and also, calling go install application/utility does give me a package

Comment: Your pastebin output stopped before the `goimports -w main.go` and `cat main.go` steps.

Comment: goimports main.go is the equivalent of goimports -w main.go and cat main.go without changing main.go, in other words, goimports -w main.go would also print the same thing... but yeah, goimports -w main.go doesn't import "application/utility"