# go build cannot find appdynamics go-sdk package

Tags: go, build, package, appdynamics

`go build` is unable to find the 'appdynamics' package, even though the GOPATH is properly set.  I downloaded the package, copied it onto the GOPATH: `~/go/src/appdynamics` and ran `go install appdynamics`. I am using go v.1.10 on Ubuntu 18.4.

Visual Studio Code is able see the package and code completion works within the IDE.  However, running `go get -fix -v appdynamics` produces the following error:

```
warning: no cgo types: exit status 1
warning: no cgo types: exit status 1
```

I have also tested this using the github.com/appdynamics namespace per the appdynamics go-sdk instructions.  Also, I am aware of all the other go build 'cannot find package' [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13214029/906048) on S.O.

Comment: There is issue may be https://github.com/pydio/cells/issues/29. It was fixed in
 go 1.11.2

Comment: this didn't work.  I upgraded to go 1.14 and I'm still having the same problem.  Is there a way to get more detail from the go runtime to see what's happening besides the --debug flag?