# GO (Golang) does not see other .go files inside the same dir

Tags: go, import, undefined

**PROBLEM:** functions exported from other packages are undefined, invisible from inside of main.go

**SOLUTION:**
Put **main.go** into a **separate folder** (name it **app** or main, doesn't matter). Only go.mod remains in root, with the folders "**app**" and "package1" "package2" etc. After this VSCode automatically added imports on save, I didn't even need to do anything. If I have main.go in root then it doesn't work (most of the time) as it doesn't "see" functions from other modules (undefined).

I found the solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214029/go-build-cannot-find-package-even-though-gopath-is-set),(see post by davidbost). The solution on this page by Andrey Dyatlov worked too for a while and then stopped working.

It took me probably 10 hours of try and error and searching.
**Hopefully the above will help others**. Thank you, everyone!

**_______________________________________________________________________**

**Original Problem Description:**

Windows 10, Go 1.17, VS Code with Go extension.

Hello, I am new to Go and I was not able to follow a single tutorial due to the following issue. When I create another .go file in the same directory (or inside a folder of the same directory) as the main.go, I receive error saying **.\main.go:7:2: undefined: SayHi**

---

main.go file:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("1st")
    SayHi()
}
```

another .go file inside /something folder:

```
package something

import "fmt"

func SayHi() {
    fmt.Println("Hi!")
}
```

Running go run main.go results in the undefined SayHi error

I googled the issue with no luck.

$ go build   // gives out the same error

$ go install  // gives out the same error

without using functions from other files  $ go run main.go  runs just fine.

I also tried **go init** with adding my github directory with no luck (by following a tutorial). I also tried the official [starting guide](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started) with **go run init**, and the exported **C**apitalized function is still undefined. What's worse is that autocomplete for the SayHi function works, yet it won't compile because undefined.

I have set PATH to C:\Users\xxx\go and put my files there, I also tried using C:\Go with no luck, it's still undefined. I'm about to give up on Go...

Comment: Import the package in the main package.

Comment: how? (in tutorials I followed they did nothing of that sort)

Comment: Try ```import "something"``` in your main file.

Comment: Continuing the tutorial will eventually get you there, or the official [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) shows how to make and import packages within a module.

Comment: import "something" doesn't work, same undefined error. I will take a look at How to Write... link

Comment: You need to qualify identifiers from another package with the package name. You cannot just use `SayHi()` from another package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It' would be hard to fix your project without knowing its current state. Please, try to start from scratch:

1. Create a directory for your project anywhere outside `$GOPATH`:

   ```
   mkdir myproject
   cd myproject
   ```
2. Run the following command to create a `go.mod` file that describes your project (module) and its dependencies; let's call the module `github.com/me/myproject`:

   ```
   go mod init github.com/me/myproject
   ```
3. Create the first file; let's call it `main.go`:

   ```
   package main

   import "fmt"
   import "github.com/me/myproject/something"

   func main() {
       fmt.Println("1st")
       something.SayHi()
   }
   ```
4. Create a directory for the package called `github.com/me/myproject/something`:

   ```
   mkdir something
   ```
5. Create a file with path `something/something.go`:

   ```
   package something

   import "fmt"

   func SayHi() {
       fmt.Println("Hi!")
   }
   ```
6. From the `myproject` directory, run `go build`.
7. Launch your first Go program:

   ```
   ./myproject
   1st
   Hi!
   ```

Comment: It worked, but I am not sure why. Obviously has something to do with the <><><>import "github.com/me/myproject/something"<><><> I don't know how to select "Best answer", I can't even vote up. Edit: I modified my old project which didn't work with step 2, added the above import and it also works, THANKS